Why does NumPy drastically slow down when I *decrease* the size of an array?
I have a 2D NumPy array, where the entries are random floats clustered tightly around 1.0, e.g. 1.015, 0.989, etc. The number of rows is n_rows = 10^4, and the number of columns is 2^13:
n_rows = 10**4
n_columns = 2**13

my_array = 1 + ((np.random.random(n_rows*n_columns).reshape((n_rows, n_columns)) - 1/2) * 2 * 0.025)

My 2020 MacBook Air with 8gb of memory says this array takes up about 655 million bytes (by writing my_array.nbytes), which does not seem to be an issue. So far so good.
Now, in my project I need to cumulatively multiply the entries in each column. To do this, I write
products = np.cumprod(my_array, axis=0)

which, by using the "%timeit" syntax in my Jupyter notebook yields the result:
6.62 s ± 258 ms per loop (7 runs, 1 loop each).
This is too slow for my purposes, so I started experimenting with the np.cumprod function and adjusting n_rows and n_columns, and in so doing, I discovered something quite bizarre: if I increase num_columns from 2^13 to 2^13 + 1, the performance improves drastically. In fact, %timeit yields 1.31 s ± 4.97 ms per loop, which is over 5X faster!
This same phenomenon (drastic speed up) holds if I use n_columns = 2^13 - 1. The same pattern is also seen if I use np.cumsum rather than np.cumprod. I can also reproduce this weird behavior when I let the number of columns be given by another power of 2, e.g. 2^12 or 2^14. However, this aberrant behavior seems to disappear when I set axis=1 in either function, and in addition the behavior vanishes when I use np.prod or np.sum.
I would be very grateful if someone could explain the reason for these strange results.
I have generated dozens of random 2D arrays with the shapes explained above and the results are the same.
I was expecting the time of execution for num_columns = 2^13 to be almost identical to the case where n_columns = 2^13 + 1 and n_columns = 2^13 - 1. I did not expect a factor of 5 difference in speed!
PLEASE NOTE. I should add that I am not asking purely out of curiosity. In my program, the 2D arrays ("my_array" above) are actually generated from multiplying two other matrices, where the second one has n_columns given by a power of 2. I have thousands of such matrices that I have pregenerated and saved in storage so that I can reproduce simulation results. If it turns out that I will not be able to speed up my code using matrices with this geometry, then I will have to erase all of my presaved matrices and generate them again from scratch, which will be a hassle for various reasons.
TO REPRODUCE MY WORK:
Please try the following in a Jupyter notebook:
Cell 1:
import numpy as np
n_rows = 10**4
n_columns = 2**13 # or 2**13 +/- 1

my_array = 1 + ((np.random.random(n_rows*n_columns).reshape((n_rows, n_columns)) - 1/2) * 2 * 0.025)

Cell 2:
%timeit products = np.cumprod(my_array, axis=0)


Just a very rough test using your example code on Windows, at the very most I'm getting around a 15% speedup with +- 1, so it doesn't seem to be massively different. I'd suggest write some code so others can run tests more easily too.

Thank you Peter. Even a 15% speed up seems pretty remarkable though. I'll edit my answer to be more easily reproduced.

Does this answer your question? Why is my program slow when looping over exactly 8192 elements?

There are two issues here: First, by going along the outer dimension. As discussed here this is not well optimized to start with (poor locality of data, each access hits a new cache line and even page, putting stress on the TLB and cache). By making it a large power of 2, you hit additional issues with every access hitting the same set in a set-associative cache

@Homer512 a bit more explanation about "hitting the same set in a set-associative cache" and this would be enough for answer imo. Or maybe link to some other source, smaller than 110 pages :D

It's just section 3.3.1 but you can also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909987/slowdown-when-accessing-data-at-page-boundaries/56910650#56910650 or and the links there.

The geometry of your array can have a big impact on how NumPy manages memory access and cache utilization, which is related to the performance anomaly you're seeing, especially when working with powers of two.
As you have previously noticed, performance much increases when you set n_columns to 2^13 + 1 or 2^13 - 1. By making this adjustment, the alignment problems are resolved and the CPU can access memory more quickly.

This is interesting. Does it only happen on certain machines or operating systems? Do you know where I could read more about this?
It would be very helpful to resolve the issue somehow and be able to use arrays with n_columns given by a power of 2, as their precursor as actually read in from storage, and each array in storage has n_columns given by a power of 2. I could erase them all and regenerate them with a "+1" offset, but that would be a major hassle.

This answer could be improved with more details and links to references where this behavior is documented

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
