# Measuring the effect of cache size and cache line size in C

Tags: c, caching

I have just read a blogpost [here](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) and try to do a similar thing, here is my code to check what is in example 1 and 2:

```
int doSomething(long numLoop,int cacheSize){
    long k;
    int arr[1000000];
    for(k=0;k<numLoop;k++){
        int i;
        for  (i = 0; i < 1000000; i+=cacheSize) arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

As stated in the blogpost, the execution time for doSomething(1000,2) and doSomething(1000,1) should be almost the same, but I got 2.1s and 4.3s respectively. Can anyone help me explain?
Thank you.

Update 1:
I have just increased the size of my array to 100 times larger

```
int doSomething(long numLoop,int cacheSize){
    long k;
    int * buffer;
    buffer = (int*) malloc (100000000 * sizeof(int));
    for(k=0;k<numLoop;k++){
        int i;
        for  (i = 0; i < 100000000; i+=cacheSize) buffer[i] = buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the execution time of doSomething(10,2) and doSomething(10,1) are still much different: 3.02s and 5.65s. Can anyone test this on your machine?

Comment: Are you using the same exact processor? Different processors have different cache sizes.

Comment: try making the array bigger and see what happens,  in the link, he is using 64MB you are using 1MB  you may never get a direct memory access.  possibly.

Comment: hmm, you are correct but I am expecting to see the difference between L1 and L2, L3 cache. Let me check with a larger array.

Comment: Please check my update1.

Comment: use valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./your program, check the Dr,Dw, then you will know the cpu cache is the main reason of your difference.

Comment: @MYMNeo, as what I read from valgrind, the misses of the 2 function calls are the same (which means the execution time should be the same), but the real execution time are different. I am not going deeper as Ben Jackson's solution worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: @navie, see this to know more about cache, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413855/why-is-transposing-a-matrix-of-512x512-much-slower-than-transposing-a-matrix-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array size of 4M is not big enough.  The entire array fits in the cache (and is in the cache after the first `k` loop) so the timing is dominated by instruction execution.  If you make `arr` much bigger than the cache size you will start to see the expected effect.

(You will see an additional effect when you make `arr` bigger than the cache:  Runtime should increase linearly with `arr` size until you exceed the cache, when you will see a knee in performance and it will suddenly get worse and runtime will increase on a new linear scale)

Edit:  I tried your second version with the following changes:

1. Change to `volatile int *buffer` to ensure `buffer[i] = buffer[i]` is not optimized away.
2. Compile with `-O2` to ensure the loop is optimized sufficiently to prevent loop overhead from dominating.

When I try that I get almost identical times:

```
kronos /tmp $ time ./dos 2
./dos 2  1.65s user 0.29s system 99% cpu 1.947 total
kronos /tmp $ time ./dos 1
./dos 1  1.68s user 0.25s system 99% cpu 1.926 total
```

Here you can see the effects of making the stride two full cachelines:

```
kronos /tmp $ time ./dos 16
./dos 16  1.65s user 0.28s system 99% cpu 1.926 total
kronos /tmp $ time ./dos 32
./dos 32  1.06s user 0.30s system 99% cpu 1.356 total
```

Answer (score 2):

With doSomething(1000, 2) you are doing the innner loop half the count of when you use doSomething(1000,1).

Your inner loop increments by cacheSize so a value of 2 gives you only half the iterations of a value of 1.  The array is sized around 4MB which is a typical virtual memory page size.

Actually I am a bit surprised that a good compiler just does not optimize this loop away since there is no variable change.  That might be part of the issue.