# How do I write a High dcache miss rate c code

Tags: c, memory

I want to try a high dcache miss rate in c code and change the associative or cache size let miss rate down....

I referenced the [How to come up with a high cache miss rate example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635562/how-to-come-up-with-a-high-cache-miss-rate-example)

try this code and use gcc elf compiler -O1 -static > a.out

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    int n = 1000 * 1000;

    int *block = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n / 10; i++) {
         int ri = rand() % n;
         block[ri] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the most cpu.dcache.miss.rate is 0.19

How do I edit the code let dcache miss rate raise above 70% or 80%?