# AVX 512 matrix multiplication with column-wise traversal on B

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, avx512

I wrote a matrix multiplication over floating point values with AVX512 intrinsics -

```
for (int i=200; i<400; i++) {
        for (int k=1200; k<1400; k++) {
            tmp=val[440000+ (k-1200)*200 + (i-200)];
            sv=_mm512_set1_ps(tmp);
            for (int j=0; j<512/16; j++) {
                cv = _mm512_loadu_ps(&y[i*512 + 16*j]);
                bv = _mm512_loadu_ps(&x[k*512 + 16*j]);
                cv = _mm512_fmadd_ps(sv, bv, cv);
                _mm512_storeu_ps(&y[512*i+16*j], cv);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you notice the line `tmp=val[440000+ (k-1200)*200 + (i-200)];`, you will notice that val is traversed in a column major order, which is why `k` is multiplied by `k`'s range.

`i`, `k` and `j` have the usual meanings where `i` and `k` are the row and column dimensions of the first matrix (`val`) and `k` and `j` are the row and column dimensions of the second matrix (`x`).

I am currently compiling the program with the flags - `gcc -O3 -march=native -mavx -mprefer-vector-width=512 -ffast-math`.

I have also tried unrolling and jamming, which resulted in the following:

```
for (int i=200; i<400; i++) {
    for (int k=1400; k<1600; k+=2) {
        sv[0] = _mm512_set1_ps(val[520000 + (k+-1400) * 200 + (i-200)]);
        sv[1] = _mm512_set1_ps(val[520000 + (k+-1399) * 200 + (i-200)]);
        for (int j=0; j<512/16; j++){
            cv = _mm512_loadu_ps(&y[i*512 + 16*j]);
            bv[0] = _mm512_loadu_ps(&x[(k+0)*512 + 16*j]);
            cv = _mm512_fmadd_ps(sv[0], bv[0], cv);
            bv[1] = _mm512_loadu_ps(&x[(k+1)*512 + 16*j]);
            cv = _mm512_fmadd_ps(sv[1], bv[1], cv);
            _mm512_storeu_ps(&y[512*i+16*j], cv);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to further optimize these loops? (Short of parallelizing the loops)

Could I trivially dispatch to `cblas_sgemm`?

Other things I have tried are -

1. Unrolling the j loop
2. Tiling the `j` loop
3. Transposing the `val` array, and making it `val[440000 + (i-200)*200 + (k-1200)]`

Comment: instead of magic numbers I would use `sizeof` and arithmetic. It will save many problems

Comment: You currently have 2 loads + 1 store per FMA, so at best you'll get one FMA per clock cycle, and then only if data is hot in L1d cache (if not you need to cache-block for locality). If you load two or four separate `sv` loop-invariant vectors, you can hopefully do multiple FMAs that reuse at least one of the inner-loop vector loads.  So hopefully the inner loop could become 4 + 1 vector loads, 4 FMAs, and 1 or 4 vector stores.  Or perhaps even load multiple `cv` *and* `bv` vectors and combine them in different ways to get higher computational intensity (ALU work per load/store)?

Comment: Making `k` the middle loop means your inner loop is not always reloading blocks from a column, causing thrashing because the stride through the column is a multiple of the cache set modulus. That is good, but it means you are doing a store in every iteration of the inner loop. That is unnecessary. You can hold several instances of `tmp` in registers, corresponding to several values of `k` and then do several `fmadd` operations before a store is necessary.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/why-is-a-naïve-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas/14532446#14532446) for related discussion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil @Peter-Cordes Updated the original post with an example of multiple `fmadd` before a store. Is this what you meant?