# Address of start block storage

Tags: c++

> The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of
>   storage.
>   If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start of a
>   block of storage whose length in bytes shall be **at least** as large as
>   the requested size.

What does that constraint mean? Could you get an example it violates?

It seems, my question is unclear.
UPD:
Why "at least"? What is the point of allocation more than requested size? Could you get suitable example?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604411/memory-allocation-deallocation

Comment: The only "constraint" I see is the case of "if it's successful", and I don't see anything that "violates". Do you care to expand on what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allowance for allocating "more than required" is there to allow:

1. Good alignment of the next block of data.
2. Reduce restrictions on what platforms are able to run code compiled from C and C++.
3. Flexibility in the design of the memory allocation functionality.

An example of point one is:

```
  char *p1 = new char[1];
  int  *p2 = new int[1];
```

If we allocate exactly 1 byte at address 0x1000 for the first allocation, and follow that exactly with a second allocation of 4 bytes for an int, the `int` will start at address 0x1001. This is "valid" on some architectures, but often leads to a "slower load of the value", on other architectures it will directly lead to a crash, because an `int` is not accessible on an address that isn't an even multiple of 4. Since the underlying architecture of `new` doesn't actually know what the memory is eventually going to be used for, it's best to allocate it at "the highest alignment", which in most architectures means 8 or 16 bytes. (If the memory is used for example to store SSE data, it will need an alignment of 16 bytes)

The second case would be where "pointers can only point to whole blocks of 32-bit words". There have been architectures like that in the past. In this case, even if we ignore the above problem with alignment, the memory location specified by a generic pointer is two parts, one for the actual address, and one for the "which byte within that word". In the memory allocator, since typical allocations are much larger than a single byte, we decide to only use the "full word" pointer, so all allocations are by design always rounded up to whole words.

The third case, for example, would be to use a "pre-sized block" allocator. Some real-time OS's for example will have a fixed number of predefined sizes that they allocate - for example 16, 32, 64, 256, 1024, 16384, 65536, 1M, 16M bytes. Allocations are then rounded up to the nearest equal or larger size, so an allocation for 257 bytes would be allocated from the 1024 size. The idea here is to a) provide fast allocation, by keeping track of free blocks in each size, rather than the traditional model of having a large number of blocks in any size to search through to see if there is a big enough block. It also helps against fragmentation (when lots of memory is "free", but the wrong size, so can't be used - for example, if run a loop until the system is out of memory that allocates blocks of 64 bytes, then free every other, and try to allocate a 128 byte block, there is not a single 128 byte block free, because ALL of the memory is carved up into little 64-byte sections).

Answer (score 3):

It means that the allocation function shall return an address of a block of memory whose size is at least the size you requested.
Most of the allocation functions, however, shall return an address of a memory block whose size is *bigger* than the one you requested and the next allocations will return an address *inside* this block until it reaches the end of it.
The main reasons for this behavior are:

1. Minimize the number of new memory block allocations (each block can contain several allocations), which are expensive in terms of time complexity.
2. Specific alignment issues.

Comment: @St.Antario I can see it now.

Comment: @Mark Why did you roll back to the revision 1? You know it does contain grammar mistakes, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, got confused by the "shell's".

Answer (score 2):

The two most common reasons why allocation 
returns a block larger than requested is

1. Alignment
2. Bookkeeping

Answer (score 1):

It may be such because in modern operating systems it is much effective to allocate memory page that can be of 512 kb. So internal malloc functionality can just alloc this page of memory, fill its beginning with some service information as to in how many sub-blocks it's divided into, theirs sizes, etc. And only after that it returns to you an address suitable for your needs. Next call to malloc will return another portion of this allocated page for instance. It doesn't matter that the block of memory is restricted to the size you requested. In fact you can heap-overflow this buffer because of no safe mechanism to prevent this sort of activity. Also you can consider alignment questions that other responders stated above. There are enough of types of memory management. You can google it if you are interested enough(Best Fit, First Fit, Last Fit, correct me if I'm wrong).