# Efficient matrix multiplications in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, bsxfun

What's the best way to do the following (in Matlab) if I have two matrices `A` and `B`, let'say both of size `m`-by-`n`:

```
C = zeros(m,m);
for t=1:n
    C=C+A(:,t)*B(:,t)';
end
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this really plain matrix multiplication i.e. `C = A * B;`?

Comment: By the way, since you mentioned efficiency, Matlab is crazy-good with matrix multiplication, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing more than

```
C = A*B';
```

where `A` and `B` are each `m`-by-`n`. I'm not sure that you're going to get more efficient than that unless the matrices have special properties.

One place where you might get a benefit from using `bsxfun` for matrix multiplication is when the dimensions are sufficiently large (probably 100-by-100 or more) and one matrix is diagonal, e.g.:

```
A = rand(1e2);
B = diag(rand(1,1e2));
C = bsxfun(@times,A,diag(B).');
```

This occurs in many matrix transforms – see the code for `sqrtm` for example (`edit sqrtm`).

Comment: @LuisMendo: I assume that you're referring to `A*B'`. The complex conjugate transpose is used because both `A` and `B` are `m`-by-`n` where `m` might not be equal to `n`. This is also consistent with the code specified by the OP. Note that `transpose` (`.'`) is used in the second case as we are just rearranging elements.

Comment: @horchler Sorry, I got confused. I thought you were applying `'` to `B` when only `.'` was required; but now I see that the OP uses `'`