# Matlab: Multiplying Matrices Efficiently and Inefficiently

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

The problem is simply for matrices `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` that are `n*n` and `x` that is a vector of length `n`, to find `E = DCBAx` in the most efficient way on Matlab, and in the least efficient way.

The most obvious way to calculate `E` is just to multiply them straight-forward

**Is this the most efficient way? What is the least efficient way?**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication ?

Comment: Least efficient really is a somewhat moot question, there is an infinite array of solutions that will perform mediocre. However, for such operations, implementing a matrix multiplication algorithm with nested loops usually performs very unfavourably compared to the inbuilt matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us create the dummy matrices and vector for this example.

```
n = 1000;
A = rand(n, n);
B = rand(n, n);
C = rand(n, n);
D = rand(n, n);
x = rand(n, 1);
```

Then we can define some function handles for the matrix products, in which we force the order of the operations

```
fun1 = @() D*C*B*A*x;
fun2 = @() (D*C*B*A)*x;
fun3 = @() (D*(C*(B*A)))*x;
fun4 = @() D*(C*(B*(A*x)));
```

A simple execution time evaluation with `timeit` shows that `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3` perform nearly in the same way, while `fun4` is about 100 times faster. The reason for this behavior is that in the first three cases we require 3 matrix products and 1 matrix-vector product, while in the last one only 4 matrix-vector products are performed. Interestingly Matlab is not able to recognize this simple optimization when it evaluates `fun1`.