# How to find the indices of nonzero rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

How to find the indices of nonzero rows in a matrix?

Example:

```
A = [
       14  0  6  9  8  17
       85 14  1  3  0  99
       0   0  0  0  0   0 
       29  4  5  8  7  46
       0   0  0  0  0   0
       17  0  5  0  0  49
]
```

the desired result :

```
   V =[1 2 4 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
   ix = any(x,2);
```

`any` check whether there is any element that is not a zero. The second argument stands for "per-row" computation.

If you want to get the numeric index, you can use `find` function:

```
   numIx = find(ix);
```

---

Another method:

```
  ix = sum(abs(x),2)~=0;
```

Comment: Nice, Didn't know this function (`any`).

Comment: @Andrey: I think we should add another line of code to find V!

Comment: @bzak - added to my answer. Note that in most of the cases a numeric index is not needed. Matlab even issues a warning (suggestion) in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[i,~] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A));

v = unique(i);
```

Result for the matrix given above:

```
v = unique(i')

v =

     1     2     4     6
```

Comment: my 2009 version of matlab gives me the error: ??? [i,~] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A))
        |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

Comment: I guess it is due to `~` which was not implemented in this version (I guess). Try `[i,j] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A));`

Comment: Strange, for me it does.

Comment: [i,j] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A))

i =

     1
     2
     4
     6
     2
     4
     1
     2
     4
     6
     1
     2
     4
     1
     4
     1
     2
     4
     6


j =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     3
     3
     3
     4
     4
     4
     5
     5
     6
     6
     6
     6

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that ab(uses) the [**`fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
idx = find(abs(A)*ones(size(A,2),1))
```