# Matlab:How to find the indices of rows without any zero in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

How to find the indices of rows without any zero in a matrix?

Example:

```
A = [
       14  0  6  9  8  17
       85 14  1  3  0  99
       0   0  0  0  0   0 
       29  4  5  8  7  46
       0   0  0  0  0   0
       17  0  5  0  0  49
]
```

the desired result :

```
V =[4]
```

Comment: @Adiel: you should post that as an answer. btw I would be more specific in using: `find(all(A ~= 0, 2))`

Comment: You may consider merging this question with your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827975/how-to-find-the-indices-of-nonzero-rows-in-a-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Since Adiel did not post an answer, I'll make their comment a CW: the command

```
V = find(all(A,2))
```

does the job, because `all(A,2)` processes every row, returning 1 if there are any nonzero entries. Then  `find` returns the indices of nonzero entries, which are the desired row numbers.

Similarly, `V = find(all(A,1))` works column-wise.