# Bitxor and Count the different rows values between two matrixes

Tags: matlab

I have two matrixes such as

```
A =

     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0
```

And B is
    B =

```
     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1
    -1    -1    -1    -1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0
```

My task is how to count the number of different row by row between A and B. For example, the values of second row A and second row B is different, then count increase 1. The values in third row A and third row B are different, then count values is 2 now. Hence, the total different values row by row between A and B is 2. How to implement it by matlab?

**Update:** Thank Nemesis for the first question. Now I have a other question with matrix A. I want implement the bitxor between rows of matrix A. For simplicity, I use the `rem` function with 2. The index of rows that xor together are store in index array. This is my code

```
index=[1 2 4] % row 1,2,4 will xor
output=rem(sum(A(index,:)),2);
```

The above code works with index size >1. When index size equals 1 that mean the output values is copied from the a row of A. For example, index=[1] then `ouput=A(1)=0     1     1     0`. My problem is that I cannot apply the above code when index size equals 1. What is happen? Could you edit for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically almost the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827975/how-to-find-the-indices-of-nonzero-rows-in-a-matrix/26827993#26827993), but with a small extension. Summarized, you can use the answer from @Andrey

```
ix = sum(sum(abs(A-B),2)~=0)

ix =

     2
```

Regarding the update of your question. The issue is, that `sum` for a single row will use `2` as direction (instead of default `1` that is what you want), since `size(...,1)==1`. You can force the direction in the following way:

```
output=rem(sum(A(index,:),1),2)
```