# MATLAB M x N x 24 array to bitmap

Tags: image, matlab, image-conversion

I am working in MATLAB.

I have a an array of M x N and I fill it with 1 or 0 to represent a binary pattern. I have 24 of these "bit planes", so my array is M x N x 24.

I want to convert this array into a 24 bit M x N pixel bitmap.

Attempts like:

```
test = image(1:256,1:256,1:24);
imwrite(test,'C:\test.bmp','bmp')
```

Produce errors.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `A` is the input `M x N x 24` sized array. I am also assuming that those `24 bits` in each of its 3D "slices" have the first one-third elements for the `red-channel`, next `one-third` for the `green-channel` and rest one-third as `blue-channel` elements. So, with these assumptions in mind, one efficient approach using the [fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) could be this -

```
%// Parameters
M = 256;
N = 256;
ch = 24;

A = rand(M,N,ch)>0.5; %// random binary input array

%// Create a 3D array with the last dimension as 3 for the 3 channel data (24-bit)
Ar = reshape(A,[],ch/3,3);

%// Concatenate along dim-3 and then reshape to have 8 columns, 
%// for the 8-bit information in each of R, G and B channels
Ar1 = reshape(permute(Ar,[1 3 2]),M*N*3,[]);

%// Multiply each bit with corresponding multiplying factor, which would
%// be powers of 2, to create a [0,255] data from the binary data
img = reshape(Ar1*(2.^[7:-1:0]'),M,N,3); %//'

%// Finally convert to UINT8 format and write the image data to disk
imwrite(uint8(img), 'sample.bmp')
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: Divakar - This solved my problem. Thank you for your help - T

Answer (score 1):

```
%some example data 
I=randi([0,1],256,256,24);
%value of each bit
bitvalue=permute(2.^[23:-1:0],[3,1,2])
%For each pixel, the first bit get's multiplied wih 2^23, the second with 2^22 and so on, finally summarize these values.
sum(bsxfun(@times,I,bitvalue),3);
```

To understand this code, try debugging it with input `I=randi([0,1],1,1,24);`

Comment: I am not sure what this is actually trying to achieve? What do I actually convert to a BMP?