# Faster alternative to INTERSECT with 'rows' - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, intersect

I have a code written in Matlab that uses 'intersect' to find the vectors (and their indices) that intersect in two large matrices. I found that 'intersect' is the slowest line (by a large difference) in my code. Unfortunately I couldn't find a faster alternative so far.

As an example running the code below takes approx 5 seconds on my pc:

```
profile on
for i = 1 : 500
    a = rand(10000,5);
    b = rand(10000,5);
    [intersectVectors, ind_a, ind_b] = intersect(a,b,'rows');
end
profile viewer
```

I was wondering if there is a faster way. Note that the matrices (a) and (b) have 5 columns. The number of rows don't necessary have to be the same for the two matrices.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Any other constraint, like maybe they are arrays of integers? Single digit numbers?

Comment: the numbers inside the matrices are integers, but stored as doubles

Comment: do you know anything about the numbers? Are they e.g. sorted?

Comment: Hi Jonas. No, the numbers can take any combination. So far, I believe the work done by Divakar is pretty impressive and good enough for my work, however a faster way is always better if you want to investigate more. BTW, the numbers don't have to be stored as doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion and solution codes

You can use an approach that leverages [**`fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) to convert those `5` columns of input arrays into one column by considering each column as a significant "digit" of a single number. Thus, you would end up with an array with only column and then, you can use `intersect` or `ismember` without `'rows'` and that must speedup the codes in a big way!

Here are the promised implementations as function codes for easy usage -

**intersectrows_fast_v1.m:**

```
function [intersectVectors, ind_a, ind_b] = intersectrows_fast_v1(a,b)

%// Calculate equivalent one-column versions of input arrays
mult = [10^ceil(log10( 1+max( [a(:);b(:)] ))).^(size(a,2)-1:-1:0)]'; %//'
acol1 = a*mult;
bcol1 = b*mult;

%// Use intersect without 'rows' option for a good speedup
[~, ind_a, ind_b] = intersect(acol1,bcol1);
intersectVectors = a(ind_a,:);

return;
```

**intersectrows_fast_v2.m:**

```
function [intersectVectors, ind_a, ind_b] = intersectrows_fast_v2(a,b)

%// Calculate equivalent one-column versions of input arrays
mult = [10^ceil(log10( 1+max( [a(:);b(:)] ))).^(size(a,2)-1:-1:0)]'; %//'
acol1 = a*mult;
bcol1 = b*mult;

%// Use ismember to get indices of the common elements
[match_a,idx_b] = ismember(acol1,bcol1);

%// Now, with ismember, duplicate items are not taken care of automatically as
%// are done with intersect. So, we need to find the duplicate items and
%// remove those from the outputs of ismember
[~,a_sorted_ind] = sort(acol1);
a_rm_ind =a_sorted_ind([false;diff(sort(acol1))==0]); %//indices to be removed
match_a(a_rm_ind)=0;

intersectVectors = a(match_a,:);
ind_a = find(match_a);
ind_b = idx_b(match_a);

return;
```

### Quick tests and conclusions

With the datasizes listed in the question, the runtimes were -

```
-------------------------- With original approach
Elapsed time is 3.885792 seconds.
-------------------------- With Proposed approach - Version - I
Elapsed time is 0.581123 seconds.
-------------------------- With Proposed approach - Version - II
Elapsed time is 0.963409 seconds.
```

The results seem to suggest a big advantage in favour of the `version - I` of the two proposed approaches with a whooping speedup of around **`6.7x`** over the original approach!!

Also, please note that if you don't need any one or two of the three outputs from the original `intersect` with 'rows' based approach, then both the proposed approaches could be further shortened for better runtime performances!