# Compare two matrices and get only same values per column in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab I have two different matrices.

The one is for example
    `A =[34.5, 35.8, 24.5, 32.3;
                           23.4, 33.1, 31.2, 14.6];`

And the second is:
`B =[34.5, 32.3; 36.7
                       23.4, 14.6, 65.1];`

I want to get a new one containing only the same values per column,
e.g. `C =[34.5, 32.3; 
                                                                         23.4, 14.6];`

Matrices A and B do not have the same number of columns.

Is there any matlab's function or can you help me to resolve this?

Comment: So, it might well end up with different number of common elements per row, so you would need a cell array as output, right?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, I mean columns not rows! I edited my question.

Comment: How about this `intersect(A.',B.','rows','stable').'`?

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, that's it! And then I just transponse the columns to rows.

Comment: Yes, that's being done in it. Also, you might find this useful - [`Faster alternative to INTERSECT with 'rows' - MATLAB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493795/faster-alternative-to-intersect-with-rows-matlab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) based approach could be more efficient -

```
%// Concatenate A and B
AB = sortrows([A B].')  %//'

%// Use DIFF to get a logical array of repetitions and 
%// use that to select elements from AB
out = unique(AB([false ; ~any(diff(AB,[],1),2)],:),'rows').'
```

You can replace the last line with something like this -

```
out = AB(strfind([false ; ~any(diff(AB,[],1),2)].',[0 1]),:).'
```

For an elegant solution, I think `intersect` based solution as suggested in the comments might suit -

```
out = intersect(A.',B.','rows','stable').'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
result = B(:,any(pdist2(A.', B.')==0, 1));
```