# matlab : vectorize 4D matrix sum

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, nested-loops

I need to perform in MATLAB the following calculation:

[image]

where w and v are vectors with N elements and A is a four-dimensional matrix (N^4 elements). This can be achieved by the following pedantic code:

```
N=10;
A=rand(N,N,N,N);
v=rand(N,1);
w=zeros(N,1);

for pp=1:N
  for ll=1:N
    for mm=1:N
      for nn=1:N
        w(pp)=w(pp)+A(pp,ll,mm,nn)*v(ll)*v(mm)*conj(v(nn));
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which is extemely slow. Is there any way to vectorize this kind of sum in MATLAB?

Comment: What datasizes are you actually dealing with? So, what's your actual `N`?

Comment: in the actual calculations, N should be of order ~100, so not extremely large, but this calculation is performed at every time step of a Runge Kutta integrator. Beside that, I need to average across a statistical population of Random matrices A, so vectorization would provide a significant help.

Comment: And the `*` in  `v*` indicates transpose?

Comment: @kkuilla `Conjugate` I suppose.

Comment: is `A` a sparse matrix?

Comment: @kkuilla : yes it is complex conjugation operation

Comment: @Shai : it's a dense matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With few [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)'s and [matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
A1 = reshape(A,N^3,N)*conj(v)
A2 = reshape(A1,N^2,N)*v
w = reshape(A2,N,N)*v
```

---

**Approach #2**

With one [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) , `reshape` and `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A1 = reshape(A,N^3,N)*conj(v)
vm = bsxfun(@times,v,v.')
w = reshape(A1,N,N^2)*vm(:)
```

---

### Benchmarking

This section compares runtimes for the two approaches listed in this post, first tested approach in [Shai's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938425/3293881) and original approach listed in the question.

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N=100;
A=rand(N,N,N,N);
v=rand(N,1);

disp('----------------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
%// .... Code from the original post   ...//
toc

disp('----------------------------------- With Shai Approach #1')
tic
s4 = sum( bsxfun( @times, A, permute( conj(v), [4 3 2 1] ) ), 4 ); 
s3 = sum( bsxfun( @times, s4, permute( v, [3 2 1] ) ), 3 );
w2 = s3*v; 
toc

disp('----------------------------------- With Divakar Approach #1')
tic
A1 = reshape(A,N^3,N)*conj(v);
A2 = reshape(A1,N^2,N)*v;
w3 = reshape(A2,N,N)*v;
toc

disp('----------------------------------- With Divakar Approach #2')
tic
A1 = reshape(A,N^3,N)*conj(v);
vm = bsxfun(@times,v,v.');
w4 = reshape(A1,N,N^2)*vm(:);
toc
```

**Runtime Results**

```
----------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 4.604767 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Shai Approach #1
Elapsed time is 0.334667 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Divakar Approach #1
Elapsed time is 0.071905 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Divakar Approach #2
Elapsed time is 0.058877 seconds.
```

**Conclusions**

The second approach in this post seems to be giving about **`80x`** speedup over the original approach.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the benchmarking! Clever way to use bsxfun. Regarding the bonus, that would have been a great idea, but in the Runge Kutta routine v is the solution at the time n and w at time n+1, so I can't precalculate it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun).

Assuming `v` is an `N`-by-1 column vectors (otherwise, permutations should be modified a little bit).

```
% sum over n (4th dim)
s4 = sum( bsxfun( @times, A, permute( conj(v), [4 3 2 1] ) ), 4 );
```

Now the interim result is only `N`-by-`N`-by-`N`.

```
% sum over m (3rd dim)
s3 = sum( bsxfun( @times, s4, permute( v, [3 2 1] ) ), 3 )
```

Continuing to the last sum

```
% sum over l (2nd dim)
w = s3*v;
```

---

<sub>Coming to think about it, have you considered using [`dot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) in its multidim version? I did not test it, but it should work (maybe some minor corrections).</sub>

```
s4 = dot( A, permute( conj(v), [4 3 2 1] ), 4 );
s3 = dot( s4, permute( v, [3 2 1] ), 3 );
w = s3*v;
```

Comment: Good use of `bsxfun`, should be efficient here!