# Replace each element in a matrix with a diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Say I have a matrix A of dimension NxV. I want to create a larger matrix of size NTxVT, i.e. I want to replace each element e of the matrix A(e) with diag(T)*A(e)., while keeping the general  orientation of the matrix (for instance, A(e) is to the left of A(e-1), so diag(T)*A(e) is to the left of diag(T)*A(e-1).

Is there a trick to accomplish this in matlab? (making each diagonal matrix and concatenating them will take forever).

Many thanks ^^

Comment: Could it be you are looking for the kron command? http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html

Comment: Won't you end up with a matrix of size `NTn x V` instead, where `Tn` is `size(T,1)` because `diag(T)` would be `size(T,1)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
A = magic(3);
T = diag([-1 1]);
kron(A,T)
```

gives

```
-8     0    -1     0    -6     0
 0     8     0     1     0     6
-3     0    -5     0    -7     0
 0     3     0     5     0     7
-4     0    -9     0    -2     0
 0     4     0     9     0     2
```

ps. I copied the idea from [this example](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/KEse97.htm#x101-12100058)

Comment: This is the way to go! Concise and fast.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `bsxfun`

```
A = magic(3);
T = [-1 1]
T = diag(T);
M=bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[3,1,4,2]),permute(T,[1,3,2,4]));
M=reshape(M,size(T).*size(A));
```

It creates a 4D-Matrix where the individual blocks are `M(:,i,:,j)`, then this is reshaped to a 2D-Matrix.

The image processing toolbox provides another solution which is very short but slow:

```
A = magic(3);
T = [-1 1]
T = diag(T);
M=blockproc(A,[1 1],@(x) x.data.*T);
```

And finally a implementation which generates a sparse matrix, which might be helpful for large T as your matrix will contain many zeros:

```
T=[-1 1];
A=magic(3);
%p and q hold the positions where the first element element is stored. Check sparse(p(:),q(:),A(:)) to understand this intermediate step
[p,q]=ndgrid(1:numel(T):numel(T)*size(A,1),1:numel(T):numel(T)*size(A,2));
%now p and q are extended to hold the indices for all elements
tP=bsxfun(@plus,p(:),0:numel(T)-1);
tQ=bsxfun(@plus,q(:),0:numel(T)-1);
%
tA=bsxfun(@times,A(:),T);
M=sparse(tP,tQ,tA);
```

When T is of size nx1 the sparse solution cuts your memory usage by a factor of roughly n/1.55.

Comment: I think, `permute(A,[3,1,4,2]).*permute(T,[1,3,2,4])` looks clearer than its `bsxfun` equivalent.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: octave user? Matlab does not support broadcasting, bsxfun is required here.

Comment: You got me ;) I switched to octave a couple of years ago. And you're right, it won't work in MatLab without `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of is to combine [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) functions:

```
B = cell2mat(arrayfun((@(x) T .* x), A, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

First, I transformed matrix `A` into a cell array of matrices `T .* x` where `x` is an element of `A` (a assumed that `T` is a matrix).

Then I used `cell2mat` to transform in back into a matrix.

Here is a complete example ([execute online](http://goo.gl/gNsNLA)):

```
A = magic(3);
T = diag([-1 1]);
B = cell2mat(arrayfun((@(x) T .* x), A, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

resulting in:

```
B =

  -8   0  -1   0  -6   0
   0   8   0   1   0   6
  -3   0  -5   0  -7   0
   0   3   0   5   0   7
  -4   0  -9   0  -2   0
   0   4   0   9   0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just indexing:

```
A = magic(3); 
T = diag([-1 1]); %// example data from Daniel's answer
[a1, a2] = size(A);
[t1, t2] = size(T);
M = A(ceil(1/t1:1/t1:a1), ceil(1/t2:1/t2:a2)).*T(repmat(1:t1,1,a1), repmat(1:t2,1,a2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`good old-fashioned matrix multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
M = reshape(diag(T)*A(:).',[size(A,1)*size(T,1) size(A,2)])
```

---

Sample run -

```
A = magic(4)
T = magic(3)
M = reshape(diag(T)*A(:).',[size(A,1)*size(T,1) size(A,2)])
```

will result in -

```
A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
T =  %// Notice that only diag(T) elements would be used to calculate M 
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
M =
   128    16    24   104
    80    10    15    65
    32     4     6    26
    40    88    80    64
    25    55    50    40
    10    22    20    16
    72    56    48    96
    45    35    30    60
    18    14    12    24
    32   112   120     8
    20    70    75     5
     8    28    30     2
```