# How to vectorize sum of vector functions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a for loop in MATLAB which calculates sum of sine functions as follows:

```
% preliminary constants, etc.
tTot = 2;
fS = 10000;dt = 1/fS; % total time, sampling rate
Npts = tTot * fS; %number of points
t = dt:dt:tTot;
c1 = 2*pi/tTot;
c2 = pi/fS;    
s = zeros(1,Npts)

% loop to optimize:
for(k=1:Npts/2)
    s = s + sin(c1*k*t - c2*k*(k-1))
end
```

Basically, a one-liner for loop that becomes really slow as `Npts` becomes large. The difficulty comes in the fact that I am summing vectors which are defined by a parameter `k`, over `k`.

Is there a way to make this more efficient by vectorizing? One approach I've taken so far is defining a matrix and summing out the result,  but this gives me an out of memory error for larger vectors:

```
[K,T] = meshgrid(1:1:Npts,t);
s = sum(sin(c1*K.*T - c2*K.*(K-1)),2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Using sine of difference formula: **`sin(A-B) = sin A cos B - cos A sin B`** that enables us to leverage [`fast matrix multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
K = 1:Npts/2;
p1  = bsxfun(@times,c1*K(:),t(:).');
p2 = c2*K(:).*(K(:)-1);
s = cos(p2).'*sin(p1) - sin(p2).'*cos(p1);
```

**Approach #2**

With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
K = 1:Npts/2;
p1  = bsxfun(@times,c1*K(:),t(:).');
p2 = c2*K(:).*(K(:)-1);
s = sum(sin(bsxfun(@minus, p1,p2)),1);
```

---

Approach #1 can be modified to bring in a smaller sized loop to accommodate for problems that have large data arrays as shown next -

```
num_blks = 100;%// Edit this based on how much RAM can handle workspace data
intv_len = Npts/(2*num_blks); %// Interval length based on number of blocks

KP = 1:Npts/2;
P2 = c2*KP(:).*(KP(:)-1);
sin_P2 = sin(P2);
cos_P2 = cos(P2);

s = zeros(1,Npts);
for iter = 1:intv_len:Npts/2
    K = iter:iter+intv_len-1;
    p1  = bsxfun(@times,c1*K(:),t(:).');
    s = s + (cos_P2(K).'*sin(p1) - sin_P2(K).'*cos(p1));
end
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I still get a memory error with this method, but I'm beginning to suspect that this is a problem with vectorization of large sums.

Comment: @Orko Yeah, I think its because your system memory can't handle such large operations in one go.

Comment: @Orko Addee a modified version to account for problems with large data arrays, check it out!

Comment: Nice hybrid approach, and clever idea with the trig identity!