# How to select specific rows based upon column attribute values in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have `[sentence cross words]` logical matrix where `value = 1` shows presence of a word in that sentence and `0` shows absence like as follows:

```
0 0 1 1

1 0 1 0

0 0 0 1

1 1 0 0
```

I have done some processing and selected specific words i.e. `2 & 3`

```
result = 2 3
```

Now, I want to select only those rows in which value of words `2 & 3` are `equal to 1` and return there row number as follows:

```
row = 1 2 4
```

This should be done for every word that is in result variable - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you are looking for something like this, assuming A as the input binary array -

```
result = [2 3]; %// select words by IDs
row = find(any(A(:,result),2))
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     0     0
row =
     1
     2
     4
```

---

For *fun-sake*, you can also use [`matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) as an alternative approach -

```
row = find(A(:,result)*ones(numel(result),1))
```

Comment: hahahahahaha. 36 seconds away from each other.  Nice.  Glad to see I was thinking along the same lines as you!

Answer (score 3):

First choose the columns that you want to extract and create a matrix that concatenates all of these columns together.  Next, use [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and operate along the columns in combination with [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to obtain the desired locations.

Therefore, given your logical matrix stored in `X`, do:

```
ind = [2 3];
matr = X(:,ind);
vals = find(any(matr, 2));
```

With your above example, we get:

```
vals =

     1
     2
     4
```

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks :). +1 to you too... don't know why there was a downvote.  I was legitimately working on this answer at the same time you were.  I hate it when people downvote and they don't give a reason.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for your answer it works, wanted to ask you if there is a way in which i can pass a variable for example: `result` which has words sored and it should automatically select which columns to select like `ind = result;` rather than giving `ind = [2 3];` because in my real scenario there are large number of columns selected

Comment: Just use `ind = result;`.  As long as `result` is a vector of columns, then the above code will work.  I just did `ind = [2 3];` in order to go with your example.