# using reshape for a mean in a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 3D (x,y,nframes) matrix/ movie ( named ch), and a logical mask (x,y). I want to do the mean of the mask pixels in each frame , at the end I get a vector of dim 1xnframes. And I want to do it with the reshape instead than frame by frame, but both results doesn't match  and I don't understand why... Could you please let me know why???

```
for i=1:nframes
    ch_aux=ch(:,:,i);    
    Mean_for(i)= mean(ch_aux(mask));
end
% C with reshape
[row,col] = find(mask);
A=ch(row,col,:);
B=reshape(A,1,length(row).^2,nframes );
Mean_res=mean(B);


plot( Mean_for,'r')
hold on
plot( Mean_res(:))

legend({'for','reshape'})
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency, you could use another vectorized solution with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) alongwith your favourite `reshape` -

```
Mean_bsxfun = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,ch,mask),[],size(ch,3)),1)./sum(mask(:))
```

Or even better, abuse the [`fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
Mean_matmult  = mask(:).'*reshape(ch,[],size(ch,3))./sum(mask(:))
```

Comment: the result will be lower than the expected mean: you average over masked pixels, you should `sum(..., 1)/sum(mask(:));`

Comment: `mean` can be mean sometimes, if you are not careful ;)

Comment: @Shai haha joke of the day! ;)

Comment: @Shai Ah yes! That was a hard-coded value, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Joke aside, I LOVE `bsxfun`, but I suspect this time it is **significantly** slower than the other proposed solutions.

Comment: @Shai Yup, matrix-mult based approach must win this one.

Comment: according to my small benchmark matrix mult is comparable to regular reshape - I suppose because it does not require any memory copies...

Comment: @Shai I would suggest trying on bigger datasizes, mat-mult wins hands down. Something like `1000 x 1000 x 100`.

Comment: I suspect it will depend on the `nnz` in the mask - if most of the mask is `true` then mat-mult should win, otherwise, it should be quicker to hand-pick the relevant rows in the `reshape`d matrix...

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution:

Using `reshape`

```
r = reshape( ch, [], size(ch,3) );
Mean_res = mean( r(mask(:),: ), 2 );
```

Benchmarking (comparing this solution to the two proposed by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29921999/1714410)) can be found [here](http://ideone.com/4y94SQ) showing:

> Shai
> Elapsed time is 0.0234721 seconds.
> Divakar 1
> Elapsed time is 0.743586 seconds.
> Divakar 2
> Elapsed time is 0.025841 seconds.

`bsxfun` is significantly slower,

---

#### What caused the error in the original code?

I suspect your problem lies in the expression `A=ch(row, col,:);`:
Suppose `ch` is of size 2-by-2-by-`n` and `mask = [ 1 0; 0 1];`, in that case

```
[rox, col] = find(mask);
```

Results with

```
row = [1,2];
col = [1,2];
```

And, obviously, `A=ch(row,col,:);` results with `A` equals `ch` exactly, which is **not** what you want...

Comment: That `ideone` runtimes seems different to me, can you run again?

Comment: @Divakar I also get inconsistent results.... I guess it depends on loads on *ideone* server. It is clear, though, that `bsxfun` is not the way to go here. Mat-mult is the Matlab-ish way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Now, I can agree with you :)