# Vectorize loop to increase efficiency

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a 3 for loops and I would like if possible to vectorize the two inner loops.

```
for t=1:size(datesdaily1)
for i=1:size(secids,1)
    sum=0;
    if inc(t,i)==1 
    for j=1:size(secids,1)
        if inc(t,j)==1 
            sum=sum+weig1(t,j)*sqrt(Rates(t,j))*rhoneutral(i,j);         
        end
    end
    b(t,i)=sqrt(Rates(t,i))*sum/MRates(t,1);
    end
end    
end
```

Any idea on how to accomplish that? Here 'weig', 'inc' and 'Rates' are (size(datesdaily1) by size(secids,1)) matrixes and 'rhoneutral' is a (size(secids,1) by size(secids,1)) matrix.

I tried but I was not able to figure out how to do it ...

Actual full code:

```
for t=1:size(datesdaily1)

rho=NaN(size(secids,1),size(secids,1));
aux=datesdaily1(t,1);
windowlenght=252;
index=find(datesdaily==aux);
auxret=dailyret(index-windowlenght+1:index,:);

numerator=0;
denominator=0;

auxret(:,any(isnan(auxret))) = NaN;
rho = corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise');
rho1 = 1 - rho;

w = weig1(t,:) .* sqrt(Rates(t,:));
x = w.' * w;
y = x .* rho;
z = x .* rho1;
numerator   = numerator   + nansum(nansum(y));
denominator = denominator + nansum(nansum(z));;

if not(denominator==0) 

alpha(t,1)=-(MRates(t,1)-numerator)/denominator;

%Stocks included
inc(t,:)=not(isnan(weig1(t,:).*diag(rho)'.*Rates(t,:)));

rhoneutral=rho-alpha(t,1).*(1-rho);


for i=1:size(secids,1)
    sum=0;
    if inc(t,i)==1 
    for j=1:size(secids,1)
        if inc(t,j)==1 
            sum=sum+weig1(t,j)*sqrt(Rates(t,j))*rhoneutral(i,j);         
        end
    end
    bet(t,i)=sqrt(Rates(t,i))*sum/MRates(t,1);
    end
end    
check(t,1)=nansum(weig1(t,:).*bet(t,:));



end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One [`vectorized`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach using [`fast matrix multiplication in MATLAB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
%// Mask of valid calculations
mask = inc==1

%// Store square root of Rates which seem to be used rather than Rates itself
sqRates = sqrt(Rates)

%// Use mask to set invalid positions in weig1 and sqRates to zeros
weig1masked = weig1.*mask
sqRates = sqRates.*mask

%// Perform the sum calculations using matrix multiplication. 
%// This is where the magic happens!!
sum_vals = (weig1masked.*sqRates)*rhoneutral'  %//'

%// Perform the outermost loop calculations for the final output
b_vect = bsxfun(@rdivide,sum_vals.*sqRates,MRates)
```

### Benchmarking

Here's a benchmark test specially dedicated to [`@Dmitry Grigoryev`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29974961/3293881) for the doubts put on `vectorization` for performance -

```
M = 200;
N = 200;

weig1 = rand(M,N);
inc = rand(M,N)>0.5;
Rates = rand(M,N);
rhoneutral = rand(N,N);
MRates = rand(M,1);

disp('--------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
%// Code from the original approach
toc

disp('--------------------------- With DmitryGrigoryev Approach')
tic
%// Code from the DmitryGrigoryev's solution
toc

disp('--------------------------- With Much-Hated Vectorized Approach')
tic
%// Proposed matrix-multiplication approach in this solution
toc
```

**Runtimes -**

```
--------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 0.104084 seconds.
--------------------------- With DmitryGrigoryev Approach
Elapsed time is 3.562170 seconds.
--------------------------- With Much-Hated Vectorized Approach
Elapsed time is 0.002058 seconds.
```

Posting runtimes for bigger datasizes might just be too embarrasing for loopy approches, way to go `vectorization`!!

Comment: Nice! Can't wait to see if this actually improves performance.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Adding runtime test results for all the approaches soon!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Check out the test results.

Comment: Well, I guess that overhead in Matlab code can explain why your approach is actually faster. What I fail to understand is why my approach is more than 10 times slower than the original. All I did is repeating the same loops twice, so I could imagine it would be twice as slow, but your results are unbelievable!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev First rule of vectorization: Never question  a solution's performance that uses matrix multiplication in MATLAB :) Rest are of course taken on a case by case basis.

Comment: I'm not questioning your solution, I compare mine with the original, and I can't see how it could be more than 10 times slower.

Comment: @Divakar, that worked perfectly. Actually I was only giving you a subset of my code. 
I have edited the original post with the full code. Can you help me on how should I implement your technique?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Well that pre-computation part might have sucked in much of the performance. In a general case anway, looking to avoid loops in MATLAB is the preferred way and if matrix-multiplication could be used, it's like heaven! That's how high level languages like MATLAB, or even something like numpy works you know.

Comment: @volcompt Try plugging in the suggested approach and see how it works? Did you do that?

Comment: @Divakar, the issue is I don't think that plugging in would work give that I have some code before. I will try to do it, but I am a totally newbie in vectorization (any help is welcome)! Thanks for all your help! edit: I think I figured it out. Though the full code is still quite slow (though faster than before!) :)

Comment: I can't figure out how to vectorize the remaining of the code. Plugging in simply does not work given that the outer loop was vectorized as well. Still thanks.

Comment: @volcompt Remove the innermost two nested loops that calculate `bet` and put in the proposed approach until `sum_vals`. These `sum_vals` values should be the same as `bet`. Thus, you would end up with just one loop which would be the outermost loop of the exisiting code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76669/discussion-between-volcompt-and-divakar).

Comment: Hi @Divakar, just wanted to thank you again for your help on this topic and on the chat. I know it has been more than a year. But I had to revisit this issue on a similar code, and your solution is flawless. 
I realized that I never answered you fully in the chat at the time. Here, again, my huge thank you. :)

Comment: @volcompt Ah that is sweet nevertheless! Good to see codes being re-used at other places, shows that the effort was worth it :)