# Replicate Kronecker tensor with repmat in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I am trying to replicate the Kron product using only repmat and reshape and I believe I am pretty close but I can't manage to do the last correct reshape.
Particularly I have problem in reshaping `A`

To make things simple let suppose we have

```
A=[1 3; 2 4]
B=[5 10; 10 5]
```

so my `kron(A,B)` is going to be a 4x4 matrix.

```
kron=[5   10  15  30
      10  5   30  15
      10  20  20  40
      20  10  40  20]
```

I am proceeding this way:

```
Y=repmat(B,2,2)
X=A(:);
X=repmat(X,1,2)';
X=X(:);
X=repmat(X,1,2);
```

which gives me the following 8x2 Matrix:

```
X= [1 1
    1 1 
    2 2
    2 2
    3 3
    3 3
    4 4
    4 4]
```

I can't just figure out how to do the correct reshape to obtain my 4x4 matrix:

```
X=[1 1 3 3
   1 1 3 3
   2 2 4 4
   2 2 4 4]
```

Then I will be able to compute:    `X.*Y=kron(A,B)`

Comment: Will you always be in dimension 2?

Comment: when running `kron(A,B)` I get `[5    10    15    30;    10     5    30    15;    10    20    20    40;    20    10    40    20]`

Comment: @m.s. U are right, I inverted Y in my matlab, I am correcting it now.

Comment: in this specific example you can just use `X = [X(1:end/2,:), X(end/2+1:end,:)]`

Comment: @BillBokeey I was trying to make something that works on generic mxn, pxq matrices

Comment: Okay, so A would be mxn and B would be pxq?

Comment: @Adriaan true that. However I came up with the 2x2 matrices just to make it easier to explain it here.

Comment: @BillBokeey yes, that was my idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach using the powerful trio of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
M = bsxfun(@times,B,permute(A,[3 4 1 2]));
out = reshape(permute(M,[1 3 2 4]),size(A,1)*size(B,1),[]);
```

If you are *hell bent* on using `repmat`, perform the calculation of `M` with it, like so -

```
M = repmat(B,[1 1 size(A)]).*permute(repmat(A,[1 1 size(B)]),[3 4 1 2])
```

Verify output by comparing against [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) for generic matrix sizes -

```
>> A = rand(4,5);
>> B = rand(6,7);
>> M = bsxfun(@times,B,permute(A,[3 4 1 2]));
>> out = reshape(permute(M,[1 3 2 4]),size(A,1)*size(B,1),[]);
>> out_kron = kron(A,B);
>> max(abs(out(:) - out_kron(:)))
ans =
     0
```

---

Here's one using [`matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) and as such must be pretty efficient -

```
[mA,nA] = size(A);
[mB,nB] = size(B);
out = reshape(permute(reshape(B(:)*A(:).',mB,nB,mA,nA),[1 3 2 4]),mA*mB,[])
```

Comment: Great, it seems flawless to me and you also provided a solution without `bsxfun` (otherwise we are pretty much back to the in-built function `kron`).

thanks,
G.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use any loops or `bsxfun`/`arrayfun`-solutions, you can do as follows:

```
[ma,na] = size(A);
[mb,nb] = size(B);
Y = repmat(B,ma,mb);
X = reshape(repmat(reshape(repmat(A(:),1,mb)',ma*mb,na),nb,1),ma*mb,na*nb);
X.*Y
```

Comment: This is pretty neat and is exactly what I was trying to do. Just sticking to repmat and reshape.