# Vectorize 2D 3D matrix product for speedup

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have the following setup

```
matrix2D_1 = zeros(40,191);
matrix2D_2 = zeros(40,191);
matrix3D_1 = zeros(40,191,191);
for j = 1:40
    for jw = 1:191
        matrix2D_1(j,jw)  = sum(squeeze(matrix3D_1(j,jw,:))'*matrix2D_2' );
    end
end
```

so I want the sum of all products of the 3rd dimension of the 3D matrix with the elements of the of the first 2D matrix which is the matrix product in

```
squeeze(matrix3D_1(j,jw,:))'*matrix2D_2'
```

The sum of these results shall then be stored in the first 2D matrix.
As I have to run this in a large loop this takes the most time in my code. I cant get my head around it how to vectorize it in a more elegant way. Any faster solution would be higly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Use [`matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) magic -

```
M = size(matrix2D_1,2);
matrix2D_1 = reshape(sum(reshape(matrix3D_1,[],M)*matrix2D_2.',2),[],M)
```

Or `sum` and then do `matrix-multiplication` -

```
matrix2D_1 = reshape(reshape(matrix3D_1,[],M)*sum(matrix2D_2,1).',[],M)
```

Comment: In my code:   --->old version: Elapsed time is 0.242785 seconds.         --->new version:
Elapsed time is 0.008497 seconds. The third one is even faster... -->0.063

Comment: @horseshoe Very awesome! That's a huge speedup indeed!

Comment: fyi one typo in the elapsed times: the third one was -->0.0063