# How to do a fast multidimensional matrix vector multiplication?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

`A` is a 3D N*N*L matrix, `x` is a N*1 vector, on which I need to do the following operation:

```
for i=1:L
    res(i)=x'*squeeze(A(:,:,i))*x
end
```

I hope to use most efficient vectorized method instead of a `for` loop. Please anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: I suggest being more specific: you don't need matrix-vector multiplication, but computing a quadratic form. But it's possible that it only makes a difference for me:)

Comment: I can't try it right now, but you might be after something like `sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[3 1 2]),reshape(x,[1 1 N])),[1 3 2]),reshape(x,[1 1 N])),2),2)`

Comment: @J.Andrew I have rolled your question back to its previous state. This is because you updated your question making both answers, including the one you accepted as "helpful" out of date. If you have a new question, please open a new question rather than expanding on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,x,bsxfun(@times,A,x.')),[],L),1)
```

With [`matrix-multiplication-fun`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
reshape(x*x.',1,[])*reshape(A,[],L)
```

Comment: Regarding the second: "are you a wizard?";)

Comment: You seem like a `fun` guy to be around.

Comment: @Adriaan I blame the *fun-tools* hanging around :)

Comment: I like the 2nd one,it seems very efficient.

Comment: I don't know what matlab is doing inside of reshape, I am wondering why it is more efficient for the 2nd compared to the first with bsxfun? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
N=10;L=5;
A = rand(N,N,L);x=rand(N,1);
C = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[3 1 2]),reshape(x,[1 1 N])),[1 3 2]),reshape(x,[1 1 N])),2),2);
C = squeeze(C(:,1,:));
```

Thanks to @AndrasDeak, though you did miss the last `squeeze` call.

Comment: I'm quite surprised it works:) Sadly (and as expected), @Divakar's answer is much more elegant.

Comment: That is exactly what we expected of course. I tried using `permute(x,[4 3 1 2])`, which started of correctly, but ended in a 4D matrix I wasn't sure on how to smack back into shape