# Can this code be vectorised further to eliminate loop?

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I am working on a ray-tracing geometry problem in MATLAB and have reached a bottleneck in my program.

The function takes in the start and end points of a ray (**lStart** and **lEnd**), a set of plane-points and normals (**pPoint** and **norms**). The function then computes the distance along the ray at which it intersects each of the planes.

Here is a reference to the original equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection#Algebraic_form

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
dists = (diag(bsxfun(@minus, pPoint, lStart) * norms')) ./ ((lEnd - lStart) * norms')';
```

Which was called in a loop such as:

```
nRays   = size(lStart, 1);
nPlanes = size(pPoint, 1);
dists   = zeros(nPlanes, nRays);

for rayCtr = 1:nRays

    dists(:, rayCtr) = (diag(bsxfun(@minus, pPoint, lStart(rayCtr, :)) * norms')) ./...
         ((lEnd(rayCtr, :) - lStart(rayCtr, :)) * norms')';

end
```

This works perfectly well for a single ray.

Given one ray **[1 x 3]** and 300 planes **[300 x 3]**, I get a **[300 x 1]** matrix with the distance of each plane intersection.

What I am struggling with is, vectorising this to work on a list of rays.

Sizes in a typical dataset are:

```
lStart, lEnd  = [14e6, 3];
pPoint, norms = [300,  3];
```

The ray processing is usually batched into tens of thousands - to fit in memory. For each batch, I'd like to eliminate the `rayCtr` loop. With this method the entire program takes just over 8 hours (32-bit, Windows, 2GB RAM).

Here are some coordinates for six planes (forming a cuboid) and two rays as a MWE:

```
pPoint = [-0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000;
          -0.5000   -0.5000    0.5000;
          -0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000;
          -0.5000    0.5000   -0.5000;
          -0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000;
           0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000]

norms = [0  0   1;
         0  0   1;
         0  1   0;
         0  1   0;
         1  0   0;
         1  0   0]

lStart = [-1 0 0;
          -1 0.25 0]

lEnd   = [1 0 0;
          1 0.25 0]
```

The expected output from the example is:

```
dists = [-Inf -Inf;
          Inf  Inf; 
         -Inf -Inf; 
          Inf  Inf; 
          0.25 0.25; 
          0.75 0.75]
```

Many thanks.

UPDATE: With the solutions proposed in the accepted answer, runtime is down to approximately 30 mins - now limited by read-write operations and voxel lookup.

Comment: Can you give a small numerical example? Which are the 1x3 and 300x3 variables?

Comment: @LuisMendo does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have input the wrong rays! Editted to fix.

Comment: Can you add a for-loop code to solve it, so that people could verify back any optimization possible?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, should I add in the for loop I was using originally to show how the code previously worked?

Comment: @AdamSroka Yes, it would be great if you can add the code that you used before vectorization to run through the entire dataset.

Comment: Can you also add the sizes of the variables `pPoint`, `norms`, `lStart` and `lEnd` as used in the actual dataset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
dists=sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@minus,...
                               permute(pPoint,[1 3 2]),permute(lStart,[3 1 2])),...
                 permute(norms,[1 3 2])),3)...
        ./(sum(bsxfun(@times,...
                      permute(lEnd-lStart,[3 1 2]),permute(norms,[1 3 2])),3))
```

This assumes that `pPoint` and `norms` are size `[nlay 3]`, while `lStart` and `lEnd` are size `[nray 3]`. The result is of size `[nlay nray]`, each corresponding to a (layer,ray) pair.

This gives the correct result for your example:

```
dists =

      -Inf      -Inf
       Inf       Inf
      -Inf      -Inf
       Inf       Inf
    0.2500    0.2500
    0.7500    0.7500
```

---

Here's another way to introduce some [`fast matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) into play for the denominator part calculations -

```
p1 = sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@minus,pPoint,permute(lStart,[3 2 1])),norms),2)
p2 = norms*(lEnd - lStart).'
dists = squeeze(p1)./p2
```

Since `lStart` is listed as a *heavy* dataset, it might be better to keep it as it is and permute things around it. Thus, one alternative approach to get `squeeze(p1)` would be with -

```
squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@minus,permute(pPoint,[3 2 1]),lStart),permute(norms,[3 2 1])),2)).'
```

Comment: wow, quick work! This worked fine for me, once my run with real data completes in a few hours, I'll trial again with this. If it works I'll dance a small jig, then accept your answer and be eternally grateful.

Comment: @AdamSroka unfortunately quick is useless if it's wrong. Luis Mendo will probably come up with a proper solution while I try to debug mine:)

Comment: Sorry, I think I gave you the wrong inputs in the MWE

Comment: @AdamSroka unfortunately I still don't get what you expect. But in your example, none of the vectors seem to be perpendicular to any of the normal vectors. This means that I don't get any zeros in the denominator, so I don't get infinities. But `dot(lEnd(1,:)-lStart(1,:),norms(1,:))` isn't zero either. Are you sure your new MCVE is correct?

Comment: No, getting over excited and being a complete doughnut I've mixed up test cases - really sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @AdamSroka no problem at all, I'm glad that it was working all along:) Which is especially good, as I couldn't find my error for the life of me:D

Comment: @AdamSroka, also, if time is crucial, you should try the original implementation as well, where the ray index was first in the operations (just switch `1 3` to `3 1` and vice versa in every `bsxfun` call). Due to matlab's column-major memory access, it's possible that there's a reasonable performance difference (since one of the indices is a few hundreds, the other millions). Then of course the output matrix is also transposed, which can be reversed by a single transpose if necessary.

Comment: I'm still baffled at the speed with which you answered, think I need to study and practice permute a lot more.

Comment: @AdamSroka thanks, but I'm still just learning. Masters like Luis Mendo and Divakar perform incredible things with `bsxfun` and `permute` and `reshape`, and in fact it's probable that they could give a more efficient solution than mine.

Comment: So with this vectorised, the total run time of the entire program (considering 300 planes and ~14,000,000 rays) went from just over 8 hours down to 29 minutes (voxel lookup is now my major bottleneck). 

I'll run it again with the new denominator code and see how it gets on. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamSroka Sorry to bother you guys again on this. Added a small edit for maybe better performance.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks again! I'll give it a run and see how it gets along. My head is now officially fried from trying to learn to abuse permute properly.

Comment: @AdamSroka I have heard that quite often from people getting *exposed* to `permute` :D It takes some getting used to I guess.

Comment: @Divakar I'm also thinking about that numerator... By separating the minus into 2 dot products, one would be easy and the other matrix-mul-able.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Give it a try. But I was reluctant about it, because with matrix-mul we would only *cut* the dimension that has a length of `3`, so I thought maybe it's not worth it.