# A method to vectorise a call to prod() for lots of arrays of varying length?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

So my problem is, I'd like to do this without the for loop. Geting the prod() of multiple vectors but of different lengths.

I am dealing with rays intersecting voxels. I typically have 1e6 rays and 1e5 voxels, but this can vary.

`intxRays` is a list of rays that have intersected voxels.

`gainList` is a one dimensional vector, each element has a value that corresponds to a specific ray voxel intersection calculated previously (actually with the help of you lovely lot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609801/can-this-code-be-vectorised-further-to-eliminate-loop)).

`rayIntxStart` and `rayIntxEnd` are vectors of indices for, where in the `gainlist` array, each ray's corresponding values start and end (they're all in order).

Here is the code and some examples and expected outputs.

```
gainSum = zeros(1, 5);

% only interested in the intx uniques
intxSegCtr = 1;

% loop through all of the unique segments
for rayCtr = 1:max(intxRays)

    if rayCtr == intxRays(intxSegCtr)

        startInd = rayIntxStart(intxSegCtr);
        endInd = rayIntxEnd(intxSegCtr);

        % find which rows correspoond to those segements
        gainVals = gainList(startInd:endInd);
        gainProd = prod(gainVals);

        % get the product of the gains for those voxels
        gainSumIdx = intxRays(intxSegCtr);
        gainSum(gainSumIdx) = gainProd;

        % increment counter
        intxSegCtr = intxSegCtr + 1;

    end
end
```

Example data for five rays and nine voxels.  Assume the voxel gain array looked like this (for simplicity) for nine voxels (used in previous step).

```
voxelGains = 10:10:90;
```

Now say rays 1 and 3 don't hit anything, ray 2 hits voxels 1 and 2, ray 4 hits voxels 2:7 
and ray 5 hits voxels 6:9

```
intxRays = [2, 4, 5];

gainList = [10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 60 70, 80, 90];

rayIntxStart = [1, 3, 9];

rayIntxEnd = [2, 8, 12];
```

For these numbers the above code would give as a result:

```
gainSum = [0, 200, 0, 5.0400e+09, 3.024e+07];
```

I hope this all makes sense.

When I developed it I was using far smaller ray and voxel numbers and it worked fine. As I'm moving up though, the major bottleneck in my code is this loop. Actually just the `gainVals` and `gainProd` assignment is like 80% and 15% of my runtime on their own.

This is the only method I can find that works, padding and the like won't work due to the sizes involved.

Is there a way to get the value I want, without this loop?

Many thanks!

Comment: your code does not give the shown output nor does it actually work. is it correct that:  SegCtr is probably intxSegCtr ; length(intxRays) should be max(intxRays) and intxSegCtr = intxSegCtr + 1; should be at the end of the loop? i feel like then it works as it should

Comment: Sorry had been away. This is a very simplified version of the actual code so there's a good chance I've translated it wrong. I'll go through it again and update. Thank you.

Comment: @Finn It has been updated, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: wb! there are a few ways to simplfy that loop and maybe more. Do the given vectors in this example get calculated somewhere else by a loop?

Comment: Thanks! Both intxRays and gainList are calculated in other functions from data extracted from an external ray-tracer (Zemax in this case).

Comment: do you happen to have a bigger data set? with 3 rays it is hard to compare the calculation time

Comment: All of the real data sets are GBs, I can try and produce something smaller maybe?

Comment: yeah that could work like enough to calculate more than a second. it just had to be enough so the random background part of the calculatoin time can be neglected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this is a very small performance boost, but it might help. for testing the matrix way without the loop a bigger data sample is needed.

These are 3 soultions, your original, an optimized and the optimized way as a oneliner. could you please try if this is already doing something for you?

```
clear all
% orignial loop through all Rays
intxRays = [2, 4, 5];
gainList = [10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 60 70, 80, 90];
rayIntxStart = [1, 3, 9];
rayIntxEnd = [2, 8, 12];
gainSum = zeros(1, 5);
tic
% only interested in the intx uniques
intxSegCtr = 1;

% loop through all of the unique segments
for rayCtr = 1:max(intxRays)

    if rayCtr == intxRays(intxSegCtr)

        startInd = rayIntxStart(intxSegCtr);
        endInd = rayIntxEnd(intxSegCtr);

        % find which rows correspoond to those segements
        gainVals = gainList(startInd:endInd);
        gainProd = prod(gainVals);

        % get the product of the gains for those voxels
        gainSumIdx = intxRays(intxSegCtr);
        gainSum(gainSumIdx) = gainProd;

        % increment counter
        intxSegCtr = intxSegCtr + 1;

    end
end
toc

clear all
%loop insted of every single one to max just through the intxRays
intxRays = [2, 4, 5];
gainList = [10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 60 70, 80, 90];
rayIntxStart = [1, 3, 9];
rayIntxEnd = [2, 8, 12];
gainSum = zeros(1, 5);
tic
for rayCtr=1:length(intxRays)
    %no if as you just go through them
    %intxRays(rayCtr) is the corresponding element

     startInd = rayIntxStart(rayCtr);
     endInd = rayIntxEnd(rayCtr);
     % find which rows correspoond to those segements
     gainVals = gainList(startInd:endInd);
     gainProd = prod(gainVals);     

    % get the product of the gains for those voxels and set them to the ray
    gainSum(intxRays(rayCtr)) = gainProd;
end
%disp(gainSum);
toc

clear all
%same as above, but down to 1 line so no additional values are generated
intxRays = [2, 4, 5];
gainList = [10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 60 70, 80, 90];
rayIntxStart = [1, 3, 9];
rayIntxEnd = [2, 8, 12];
gainSum = zeros(1, 5);
tic
for rayCtr=1:length(intxRays)
gainSum(intxRays(rayCtr))=prod(gainList(rayIntxStart(rayCtr):rayIntxEnd(rayCtr)));
end
toc
```

Comment: This is definitely faster. I had played around with something similar but eventually split it all up for ease of understanding and to isolate the bottleneck. I'll leave it a few days longer before accepting, this just in case.

Comment: So implementing it with the final solution proposed here is quicker, I'd love a solution that didn't need the for loop though.

Comment: i tried something without a loop but it takes logner as calculationg the matrizes isn't worth it for 3 rays. also are there other data variants available? i feel like it would be easier if you just had the information which  ray hit which voxel and the gain of a voxel instead of the gain list and the inidzes per ray

Comment: I have that data but due to data sizes I found it easier to develop this way. I'll have another look at this and see if I can present the question better another way.