# Faster matrix recursion in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, recursion, matrix

The matrix-recursion of the `n x n` matrices `Y_t` looks like this:

```
Y_{t} = A + \sum_{i=1}^{p} B_{i} * Y_{t-i}
```

A and B are given.

This is my attempt, but it runs slowly:

```
Y = zeros(n,n,T); %Going to fill the 3rd dimension for Y_t, t=1:T
Y(:,:,1:p) = initializingY

for t=(p+1):T
    Y(:,:,t) = A;
    for i=1:p
        Y(:,:,t) = Y(:,:,t) + B(:,:,i)*Y(:,:,t-i);
    end
end
```

Can you think of a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you please change your code so we can benchmark our propositions against your approach? I.e. a minimal data example.

Comment: As you can see, StackOverflow doesn't support TeX. Please edit your question to replace your expression with an image if it's needed.

Comment: @horchler That's fair enough for a small formula like this though, don't you think?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: As TeX is not required or supported for SO, attempting to use it clutters questions, decreases quality, and is unhelpful to users unfamiliar with TeX. There are [straightforward workarounds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164286).

Comment: @horchler I couldn't use a workaround because I didn't have the required reputation to post images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of using clever mathematical tricks to reduce the number of operations, the best shot is to optimize the memory access. That is: avoid `subsref`ing, increase the locality of your code, reduce the cache misses by manipulating short arrays instead of large ones.

```
n = 50;
T = 1000;
p = 10;


Y = zeros(n,n,T);
B = zeros(n,n,p);
A = rand(n);
for t = 1:p
        Y(:,:,t) = rand(n);
        B(:,:,t) = rand(n);
end

fprintf('Original attempt: '); tic;
for t=(p+1):T
        Y(:,:,t) = A;
        for k=1:p
                Y(:,:,t) = Y(:,:,t) + B(:,:,k)*Y(:,:,t-k);
        end;
end;
toc;

%'This solution was taken from Divakar'
fprintf('Using reshaping: '); tic;
Br = reshape(B(:,:,1:p),n,[]);
for t=(p+1):T
        Yr = reshape(permute(Y(:,:,t-(1:p)),[1 3 2]),[],n);
        Y(:,:,t) = A + Br*Yr;
end;
toc;

%'proposed solution'
Y = cell(1,T);
B = cell(1,p);
A = rand(n);
for t = 1:p
        Y{t} = rand(n);
        B{t} = rand(n);
end

fprintf('Using cells: '); tic;
for t=(p+1):T
        U = A;
        for k=1:p
                U = U + B{k}*Y{t-k};
        end;
        Y{t} = U;
end;
toc;
```

For setups given in my example I get a two-fold speed increase for a decent machine (i5 + 4Gb, MATLAB R2012a). I am curious how well it does on your machine.

Comment: i5 2.7 GHz, 8GB DDR3, Matlab R2015a: 0.11 vs 0.06 sec on average.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I got quite similar results (0.12 vs 0.065). Thanks for confirming. :-)

Comment: Wow, this is really impressive, your solution works much better than using clever tricks actually!

Comment: @Sh3ljohn IMHO, when no algorithmic complexity reduction in sight, the first effort should be to help the hardware help you. However, for this case I think that there will be no increase in speed from matrix sizes above cache size.

Comment: :) I just re-edited sorry I stupidly tested without actually implementing the reshaping solution; it is actually doing better than using cells, but it's still quite impressive that you can gain so much time in a high-level language like Matlab, good to know!

Comment: @CST-Link Thanks for taking the time to write the benchmark code. I will post in that fashion from now on. Your code is easily readable and amazingly quick!

Answer (score 5):

You can *kill* the inner loop with [`matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) after some `reshaping` & `permuting`, like so -

```
Y = zeros(n,n,T);
%// Y(:,:,1:p) = initializingY
for t=(p+1):T
    Br = reshape(B(:,:,1:p),n,[]);
    Yr = reshape(permute(Y(:,:,t-(1:p)),[1 3 2]),[],n);
    Y(:,:,t) = A + Br*Yr;
end
```

Comment: I was trying to do exactly this; it might not seem trivial to everyone that you can actually multiply the "long-side" of `B` once resized. This is because the sum in the recursion effectively adds up matrix elements along the third dimension. That way we essentially merge the sums due to matrix multiplication on the one hand, and due to recursion on the other.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Exactly! There are reductions at two dims - One with the original `matrix-mul` and one because of the recursion, that is being done with one `matrix-mul` after that reshaping. It was quite a question, a good one really!

Comment: @Divakar Thank you very much. This is amazing! Can you think of a similar way to do this for a recursion in quadratic form like this: Y_t= A + \sum_{i=1}^{p} B_i * Y_(t-i) * B_i ' ?