# Fast logarithm calculation

Tags: python, c++, matlab, math, numpy

All the code was run on the same machine on linux.

In python:

```
import numpy as np
drr = abs(np.random.randn(100000,50))
%timeit np.log2(drr)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 77.9 ms per loop

In C++ (compiled with g++ -o log ./log.cpp -std=c++11 -O3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
std::mt19937 e2(0);
std::normal_distribution<> dist(0, 1);
const int n_seq = 100000;
const int l_seq = 50;
static double x[n_seq][l_seq];
for (int n = 0;n < n_seq; ++n) {
  for (int k = 0; k < l_seq; ++k) {
    x[n][k] = abs(dist(e2));
    if(x[n][k] <= 0)
      x[n][k] = 0.1;
    }
  }
 clock_t begin = clock();

 for (int n = 0; n < n_seq; ++n) {
   for (int k = 0; k < l_seq; ++k) {
     x[n][k] = std::log2(x[n][k]);
       }
  }
  clock_t end = clock();
```

Runs in 60 ms

In MATLAB:

```
abr = abs(randn(100000,50));
tic;abr=log2(abr);toc
```

Elapsed time is 7.8 ms.

I can understand the speed difference between C++ and numpy, but MATLAB beats everything.
I've come across
http://fastapprox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fastapprox/src/fastonebigheader.h
but this does only float, not double, and I'm not sure how to convert it to double.

I also tried this:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/approximate-0.2.2.1/src/cbits/fast.c
which has fast log functions, and when compiled as a numpy ufunc, runs in 20 ms, which is great, but the loss in accuracy is significant.

Any ideas on how to achieve the magical log2 speed that MATLAB gets?

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for comments, that was very fast and very helpful! Indeed, the answer is parallelisation, i.e. spreading the load on several threads. Following @morningsun suggestion,

%timeit numexpr.evaluate('log(drr)')

gives 5.6 ms, which is on par with MATLAB, thank you! numexpr is MKL enabled

Comment: Vectorisation and parallelisation.

Comment: This is a typical [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) scenario. Explore vectorization technics on C++ code first. For example, try [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/).

Comment: The C++ compiler can't unloop the log2() calls, so it spends a lot of time keeping track of the loop indexes. And as IKavanagh says, matlab parallelizes the computation. You could easily do it with [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/).

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication I guess the MAGMA and BLAST packs of MATLAB are the magic words. This question deals with the loops in C++ and Java, whilst MATLAB vectorises everything under the hood

Comment: The Python module [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) would also be interesting to benchmark. If you can get MKL (VML) enabled it'll do SIMD and threading on the fly. It doesn't do `log2` directly, so use  `log(a)/log(2.0)`

Comment: how about using cuda / openCL

Comment: One thing - if you have to deal with matrices which are huuuge and won't fit into RAM in dense format, **numexpr** may not be a solution to your problems. **numexp** is not compatible with the scipy sparse matrix format (had an issue with that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824617/numexpr-doesnt-recognize-float-type-sparse-matrix)

Comment: @ElBrutale Since taking the log is an elementwise operation you only need  the values stored in the sparse array, which you can easily access via its `.data` attribute.

Comment: @ali_m I agree, good point. However, for similar, common arithmetic operations which are not element-wise, this library just won't work. Posted it in case people need similar, but non-element-wise operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that ALL below are float32, not double precision.

**UPDATE**:
I've ditched gcc completely in favour of Intel's icc. It makes ALL the difference when performance is critical and when you don't have time to fine-tune your "compiler hints" to enforce gcc vectorization (see, e.g. [here](http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/))

**log_omp.c**,

GCC: gcc -o log_omp.so -fopenmp log_omp.c -lm -O3 -fPIC -shared -std=c99

ICC: icc -o log_omp.so -openmp loge_omp.c -lm -O3 -fPIC -shared -std=c99 -vec-report1 -xAVX -I/opt/intel/composer/mkl/include

```
#include <math.h>
#include "omp.h"
#include "mkl_vml.h"

#define restrict __restrict

inline void log_omp(int m, float * restrict a, float * restrict c);

void log_omp(int m, float * restrict a, float * restrict c)
{
   int i;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(m,a,c) private(i)
   for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
      a[i] = log(c[i]);
   }
}

// VML / icc only:
void log_VML(int m, float * restrict a, float * restrict c)
{
   int i;
   int split_to = 14;
   int iter = m / split_to;
   int additional = m % split_to;

//   vsLn(m, c, a);
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(m,a,c, additional, iter) private(i) num_threads(split_to)
   for (i=0;i < (m-additional); i+=iter)
     vsLog10(iter,c+i,a+i);
     //vmsLn(iter,c+i,a+i, VML_HA);

   if (additional > 0)
     vsLog10(additional, c+m-additional, a+m-additional);
     //vmsLn(additional, c+m-additional, a+m-additional, VML_HA);
}
```

**in python:**

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int, c_void_p
def log_omp(xs, out):
    lib = CDLL('./log_omp.so')
    lib.log_omp.argtypes = [c_int, np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32), np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
    lib.log_omp.restype  = c_void_p
    n = xs.shape[0]
    out = np.empty(n, np.float32)
    lib.log_omp(n, out, xs)
    return out
```

**Cython code (in ipython notebook, hence the %% magic):**

```
%%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
import  numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport log

from cython.parallel cimport prange
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def cylog(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] a not None,
        np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = np.empty((a.shape[0]), dtype=a.dtype)
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    with nogil:
        for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
            out[i] = log(a[i])
    return out
```

**Timings:**

```
numexpr.detect_number_of_cores() // 2
28

%env OMP_NUM_THREADS=28
x = np.abs(np.random.randn(50000000).astype('float32'))
y = x.copy()

# GCC
%timeit log_omp(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop
# ICC
%timeit log_omp(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.6 ms per loop
%timeit log_VML(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop

%timeit cylog(x, out=y)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

numexpr.set_num_threads(28)
%timeit out = numexpr.evaluate('log(x)')
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop
```

So numexpr seems to be doing a better job than (poorly) compiled gcc code, but icc wins.

Some resources I found useful and shamefully used code from:

http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/Optimization_Bakeoff.html

https://gist.github.com/zed/2051661