# Matlab: multiplying rows of a matrix by vector elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

Let `v` be a row vector (`1 x n` matrix) and `M` be a `n x m` matrix. 
I use the following piece of code to create a "weighted vector" (I hope the comments explain what it's supposed to be doing):

```
weighted_M = bsxfun(@times,v',M);
%creates a matrix with the i-th row of M being weighted (multiplied) by the i-th element of v
weighted_v = sum(weighted_M);
%sums the columns of weighted_M
```

Now the actual question: I have to do the same calculation for a lot of input vectors `v`. So instead I would like to input a matrix `V` that contains the vectors `v` as rows and output a matrix that contains the weighted vectors as rows. Is there any way to do this without using for loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `V` is of size `[k,n]` and `M` is of size `[n,m]`, and you're looking for the `k` weighted vectors, then you might simply need

```
weighted_vs = V*M;
```

an element of which is equal to

```
weighted_vs_ij = (V*M)ij = sum_l V_il * M_lj
```

First you multiply each row of `M` with a corresponding element of `V` (`V_il * M_lj` above for a fix `i`), then sum up as a function of the first index.

The result are the `k` weighted row vectors, each of length `m`.

Comment: Very useful thank you! (also I'm feeling slightly stupid now not realizing that it's just ordinary matrix multiplication).
Do you happen to know anything about the runtime of this operation?

Comment: @NumRok only that [it's as fast as it gets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication):) If it's doable with matrix operations, use that. If it's not, use `bsxfun` if it's doable with that. If it's not, use a loop.