# Vectorize Triple Loop - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, processing-efficiency, bsxfun

I have the following large, very inefficient loop.

```
P is a [2000 x 200 x 5] matrix
D is a [2000 x 200 x 5] matrix
S is a [200 x 1005] matrix
PS is a [2000 x 1000 x 5] matrix
```

I want to compute the following loop:

```
for k=1:2000
   for n=1:200
      for t=1:5
          P(k,n,t) = sum(S(n,t+1:t+1000) .* PS(k,1:1000,t));
      end
   end
end
```

Obviously this is very inefficient. I tried `parfor`, but I would rather a vectorized solution. I tried couple of things with `bsxfun`, but also never managed to get it working.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you a small sample data and the expected result,,please? It would help to verify any answers.

Comment: The data comes from a long code. 
I think for the purposes at hand any random data should do the trick:
P = rand( 2000,200,5);
D = rand( 2000,200,5);
S = rand( 200,1005);
PS = rand( 2000,1000,5);
Thank you!

Comment: @volcompt please add data (or random data) to your question (i.e. not in the comments) and perhapd change the scale of the problem for the example or else replace the  `1000`, `200` and `5` with variables we can alter to work on a smaller problem. Also, you should post your `bsxfun` attempts and tell us where they go wrong. Lastly, your current code completely ignores the first column of `S`, is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an almost (almost because we still have a loop, but with only 5 iterations) vectorized approach using [`powerful matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) -

```
out = zeros(2000,200,5);
for t=1:size(P,3) %// size(P,3) = 5
    out(:,:,t) = PS(:,:,t)*S(:,t+1:t+1000).';
end
```

---

Runtime tests and verify output -

```
%// Inputs
D = rand(2000,200,5);
S = rand(200,1005);
PS = rand(2000,1000,5);

disp('--------------------- No Matrix-mult-fun')
tic
P = zeros(2000,200,5);
for k=1:2000
   for n=1:200
      for t=1:5
          P(k,n,t) = sum(S(n,t+1:t+1000) .* PS(k,1:1000,t));
      end
   end
end
toc

disp('--------------------- Fun fun Matrix-mult-fun')
tic
out = zeros(2000,200,5);
for t=1:size(P,3) %// size(P,3) = 5
    out(:,:,t) = PS(:,:,t)*S(:,t+1:t+1000).';
end
toc

error_val = max(abs(P(:)-out(:)))
```

Output -

```
--------------------- No Matrix-mult-fun
Elapsed time is 70.223008 seconds.
--------------------- Fun fun Matrix-mult-fun
Elapsed time is 0.624308 seconds.
error_val =
     1.08e-12
```

Comment: Of, course... Whom else....? :-) The summation is done by the matrix multiplication, I presume?

Comment: That was impressive. Thank you Divakar!

Comment: @Divakar - on a sidenote that is unrelated to your code: you can add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before `code` sections where you don't need syntax highlighting to happen (such as in the _Output_ box in your answer).

Comment: @Dev-iL Hmm, would see how to use it in future posts, thanks for chipping in with that info!