# How to reduce for loops for Hartley transform?

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, fft, vectorization

I am currently working on 2D Hartley transform. The code is shown below:

```
for u=1:size(img,1)
    for v=1:size(img,2)
        for x=1:size(img,1)
            for y=1:size(img,2)
                a = 2*pi*u*x/size(img,1);
                b = 2*pi*v*y/size(img,2);
                temp= img(x,y)*(cos(a+b) + sin(a+b));
                X(u,v)= X(u,v)+temp;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It has 4 `for` loops and it takes a very long time to execute this. Is there any method to make it more efficient by reducing the amount of `for` loops? Anything regarding this would be very helpful.

The formula used for this 2-D Hartley transform is shown below:
[image]

Reference:Separable two-dimensional discrete Hartley transform by Andrew B. Watson and Allen Poirson.

Answer (score 3):

If you can fit into memory, you can use `bsxfun` with some additional singleton dimensions:

```
N = size(img,1);
M = size(img,2);
x = [1:N].'; %' vector of size N x 1 ( x 1 x 1)
y = 1:M;     %  vector of size 1 x M ( x 1 x 1)
u = permute(1:N,[1 3 2]); %vector of size 1 x 1 x N ( x 1)
v = permute(1:M,[1 3 4 2]); %vector of size 1 x 1 x 1 x M

a = 2*pi/N*bsxfun(@times,u,x); % N x 1 x N x 1
b = 2*pi/M*bsxfun(@times,v,y); % 1 x M x 1 x M
apb = bsxfun(@plus,a,b); % N x M x N x M
%img is N x M (x 1 x 1)

X2 = squeeze(sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,img,cos(apb)+sin(apb)),1),2));
```

Admittedly this is quite brute-force, one could probably come up with a more memory-efficient solution. The solution heavily utilizes that every array implicitly possesses an infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions, which I tried to note in the comments.

Comparison to your original looping version with `N=20; M=30; img=rand(N,M);`:

```
>> max(max(abs(X-X2)))
ans =
     1.023181539494544e-12
>> max(max(abs(X)))
ans =
     3.091143465722029e+02
```

which means they give the same solution within machine precision.

Answer (score 3):

Andras and Divakar pretty much suggested the same method that I was in the middle of writing.  As such, this answer will simply provide you with a method for speeding up using your canonical implementation.

You can eliminate the pair of nested `for` loops that use `x` and `y` as variables by manually specifying a [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) of spatial coordinates that span the extent of the image.  Also, the transform in your equation starts indexing from **0**, yet your code is starting from 1.  You'll need to start indexing at 1 with MATLAB, but the compute the terms in the equation, you need to start from 0.  As such, when you compute `a` and `b`, you'll have to subtract 1 from `x`, `y`, `u` and `v`.

In any case, you can then compute element-wise products and sum all of the values together.  It's also a good idea to **pre-allocate** the output for efficiency:

```
%// Change - preallocate
X = zeros(size(img));
%// New - define spatial coordinates
[x,y] = ndgrid(0:size(img,1)-1, 0:size(img,2)-1);
for u=1:size(img,1)
    for v=1:size(img,2)
        %// Change
        a = 2*pi*(u-1)*x/size(img,1);
        b = 2*pi*(v-1)*y/size(img,2);
        temp = img.*(cos(a+b) + sin(a+b));
        %// Change
        X(u,v) = sum(temp(:));        
    end
end
```

You will hopefully get better performance improvements.  Compare this one with Andras's or Divakar's solution and see which one you're comfortable in using.

Comment: Why not just `X = zeros(size(img))`?

Comment: Check the code again? Numbers seems to be different.

Comment: @Divakar because rayryeng fixed the semantic problem: the formula sums from 0, while OP sums from 1. So our solution gives identical results, rayryeng's solution probably gives a correct one;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ah yes, didn't notice that in the formula, thanks! :)

Comment: @Divakar yup OP needs to sum from 0 not 1. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`fast matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) for a vectorized solution -

```
%// Store size parameters
[m,n] = size(img);

%// Get vectorized versions of a and b
A = 2*pi*(1:m).'*(1:m)/m;
B = 2*pi*(1:n).'*(1:n)/n;

%// Add vectorized a and b's to form a 4D array. Get cos + sin version.
AB = bsxfun(@plus,permute(A,[1 3 2 4]),permute(B,[3 1 4 2]));
cosAB = cos(AB) + sin(AB);

%// Finally bring in magic of matrix-multiplication for final output
Xout = reshape(img(:).'*reshape(cosAB,m*n,[]),m,n);
```

Comment: I knew it!;) Efficient as always.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well the bottleneck seems to be the cosine and sine calculations, too bad really.

Comment: @AndrasDeak .. and the *co-partner*

Comment: All the codes provided work very well on a small set of values, but when I try to apply on an image of size 480 x 640, bsxfun gives me an error which says 'array exceeds maximum array size preference'. How do I go about with this?

Comment: @shreyaskamath For memory exceed error, you might want to go with a partially vectorized solution, something like suggested in [`Ray's solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34276759/3293881).