# Fast way for vector/array multiplication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I am looking for a fast and flexible way to compute the following in Matlab without using a loop:

```
c = 1:5;
A = reshape(1:5^3,5,5,5);
res= c(1)*A(:,:,1)+...+c(5)*A(:,:,5)
```

I think, working with

```
sum(A,3)
```

could be a nice way as long as I am able to perform the multiplication along the third dimension. One solution (but with loops) would be:

```
val = zeros(length(c),length(c))
for i = 1:length(c)
    val = val+c(i)*A(:,:,i)
end
```

I am just wondering if this can be done in a simpler (and more elegant) way avoiding the loop.

Comment: Clarify a liitle bit better your question . you want to multiple what?

Comment: I want  to obtain res at the end of the day.. So in other words, I would like to multiply the whole Matrix A(:,:,1) with the scalar c(1), the whole Matrix A(:,:,2) with the scalar c(2) and so on...at the end I want to sum up each of those five matrices, such that res is a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect job for [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
res = sum(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(c,[3,1,2])),3)
```

You send `c` to the third dimension using `permute(c,[3,1,2])`. Then, by calling `bsxfun`, each of the matrices in `A` is multiplied by the corresponding (permuted) `c`. Finally, you can do a `sum` over the third dimension.

Answer (score 6):

You can reshape `A` from `3D` to `2D`, use the [`very efficient matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication), which will give you a `1D` array and finally reshape back to `2D` for the final output, like so -

```
res = reshape(reshape(A,[],size(A,3))*c(:),size(A,1),[])
```