# Is there any way to disable MKL in matlab in order to test the Flops complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: matlab

Matlab is an efficeve tool to do numerical experiments. Then, I find that many papers like using it to test the Flop Complexity of an algorithm (e.g., regression, svd).

However, as I have learnt from others, Matlab uses [Intel MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) for Matrix Multiplication.  This is highly optimized code taking advantage of all the cores and their Vector Processing Units ([SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) / [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)), and optimized for the cache layout in the CPU.

This means directly using Matlab cannot truly test flops complexity.

My question is then: how to disable MKL or something eles in Matlab  in order to test the Flop Complexity of an algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the 'code optimization' in operations like matrix multiplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963463/how-to-avoid-the-code-optimization-in-operations-like-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: they don't actually count the flops but they are using theoretical worst-case upper bounds