# uchar/float matrices - element by element division and multiplication

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix

I want to divide a matrix `cv::Mat src` of type `CV_8UC1` with a scalar of type `float` and the result stored in a new matrix `srcN` of type `CV_32FC1`:
I'm doing this at the moment:

```
for(unsigned j=0;j<src.rows;j++)
    for(unsigned i=0;i<src.cols;i++)
        srcN.at<float>(j,i) = ((int) src.at<uchar>(j,i))/A;
```

Which is not very fast. I want to do it like this: `srcN=src/A;` but I don't get the right values in srcN. Is there any way to do that?

Another question: MATLAB (which literally means MATrix LABoratory) is very fast in operations with matrices, how can I make my code as fast as matlab with `c++/opencv`?

Comment: [This is why MATLAB is very fast in matrix operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication). They use BLAS/MAGMA Fortran libraries.

Comment: @DanMašek I think it's the same !?
the issue is with uchar in src which should be int before dividing or multiplying

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV Oh, right, that was irrelevant -- for some reason I though there wasn't an overload for Mat/scalar. | The cast to `int` in your loop body is redundant -- since `A` is float, the other operand of the division is implicitly converted to float. So, what you really want is `srcN = cv::Mat_<float>(src) / A;`

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks that what I was looking for.. However it does take the same time as with loops

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV Thinking about this more, what you're actually doing is converting the `Mat` to a different type, while scaling at the same time. This is exactly what `convertTo` can do. `src.convertTo(srcN, CV_32FC1, (1 / A));`