# Improving Fortran matrix exponential performance (Expokit slower than Matlab, Python)

Tags: python, matlab, fortran, gfortran

I'm working on a simulation where the bottleneck is performing a large number of complex double precision matrix exponentials, and am finding that while Fortran (Expokit) works well for small matrices, for larger ones it performs worse than Matlab or Python.

I have included a model program showing similar behavior below, though it requires larger matrices to show the performance difference. Looking at  the profiler and the [source code](https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/fortran/zgpadm.f) it seems that Expokit spends most of its time calling zgemm(), and so my only thought is an issue with my BLAS installation. Otherwise I don't understand why Fortran would be performing worse than Matlab or Python. I would greatly appreciate any insight into improving the performance of the Fortran matrix exponential code.

> Results for 10000 matrices (4x4, 8x8, 30x30, 60x60, 80x80):
>
> Matlab (s): 0.91, 0.97, 2.36, 5.45, 8.69
>
> Python (s): 2.59, 2.89, 9.70, 35.4, 72.7
>
> Fortran, Expokit (s): 0.037, 0.12, 4.14, 30.6, 74.9
>
> Fortran, Expokit, OpenMP with 8 cores (s): 0.0039, 0.016, 0.52, 3.87,
>   9.53

Fortran code:

```
    subroutine expokit_test()

    use omp_lib
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15, 307), size=80
    complex(wp), parameter :: i = (0, 1._wp)
    integer :: count, a, b
    real(wp) :: wtime
    complex(wp) :: mat_exp(size, size),  mat(size, size), val

    val = 1E-8_wp
    mat = 0._wp

    do a = 1, size
        do b = 1, size
            mat(a, b) = a * b
        end do
    end do

    call omp_set_num_threads(8)
    wtime = omp_get_wtime()
    !$omp parallel do default(private) &
    !$omp& shared(mat, val)
    do count = 1, int(1E4)
        mat_exp = expm_complex(-i * mat * val)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
    wtime = omp_get_wtime () - wtime
    write(6, *) 'expm_complex', sngl(wtime)

end subroutine expokit_test

function expm_complex(A) result(B)
        ! Calculate matrix exponential of complex matrix A using Expokit

        use iso_fortran_env
        implicit none

        integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
        complex(wp), dimension(:, :), intent(in) :: A
        complex(wp), dimension(size(A, 1), size(A, 2)) :: B

        integer, parameter :: ideg = 2 ! Pade approximation, 6 is reccomended but 2 appears to be stable
        complex(wp) :: t = 1._wp
        complex(wp), dimension(4 * size(A, 1) * size(A, 2) + ideg + 1) :: wsp
        integer, dimension(size(A, 1)) :: iwsp
        integer :: iexp, ns, iflag, n
        n = size(A, 1)

        call ZGPADM(ideg, n, t, A, n, wsp, size(wsp, 1), iwsp, iexp, ns, iflag)
        B = reshape(wsp(iexp : iexp + n * n - 1), [n, n])

    end function expm_complex
```

Matlab code:

```
size = 80;

for a=1:size
    for b=1:size
        A(a, b) = 1E-9 + (a * b);
    end

end

tic
for test=1:1E4
    t=expm(-1i*A*1E-8);
end
toc
```

Python code:

```
size = 80
mat = np.ones((size, size))

for a in range(0, size):
    for b in range(0, size):
        mat[a, b] = ((a+1) * (b+1))

mat = mat + 1E-9

start = time.time()
for loop in range(0, int(1E4)):
    test = la.expm(-1j * mat * 1E-8)


end = time.time() - start
print('time taken', end)
```

Comment: So what kind of BLAS implementation do you use then?

Comment: [Why is MATLAB so fast in matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6058139/5211833)

Comment: I'm using gfortran installed using Cygwin with default LAPACK/BLAS (not sure which implementation), though I have also tested on a Ubuntu dual boot also using gfortran and default LAPACK installation and get similar performance.

Comment: So install some faster BLAS and test it. It is really hard to argue about performance of a computer we cannot access.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you have any specific recommendation?

Comment: Fortran is a column major language.  Interchange the do-loops that initialize `mat(a,b)`.  Striding through memory with the larger matrix may be blowing out the cache.

Comment: It does not matter too much, just some optimized BLAS. OpenBLAS, MKL, GotoBLAS, ATLAS, any of them. Also fix what evets suggests.

Comment: In looking at the Fortran code again, I think the call to `RESHAPE` with an array section may be slow.  I suspect most compilers will make a temporary copy of the array section.

Comment: How would you recommend improving that @evets? I assume assigning a new variable to the array section would be the same as the compiler doing so.