# Rewriting MATLAB code with nested loops in Python with fast execution

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, cython, nested-loops

Here is a nested loop, where the inner one indices depend on the outer one, with the following parameters:

```matlab
f = rand(1,70299)
nech=24*30*24
N=length(f);
xh=(1:nech)/24;
```

In MATLAB:

```matlab
sf2(1:nech)=0.;
sf2vel(1:nech)=0.;
count(1:nech)=0.;

for i=1:nech
    for j=1:N-i-1
        sf2(i)=sf2(i)+(f(j+i)-f(j))^2;
        count(i)=count(i)+1; 
    end
    sf2(i)=sf2(i)/count(i);
end
```

In Python:

```py
def structFunPython(f,N,nech):
    sf2 = np.zeros(N)
    count = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(nech):
        indN = np.arange(1,N-i-1)
        for j in indN:
            sf2[i] += np.power((f[i+j]-f[j]),2)
            count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] = sf2[i]/count[i]
    return sf2
```

With cython:

```py
import cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
def structFun(np.ndarray f,N,nech):
    cdef np.ndarray sf2 = np.zeros(N), count = np.zeros(N),
    for i in range(nech):
        indN = np.arange(1,N-i-1)
        for j in indN:
            sf2[i] += np.power((f[i+j]-f[j]),2)
            count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] = sf2[i]/count[i]
    return sf2
```

Executions times:

```
Matlab: 7.8377 sec
Python: 3651.35 sec
Cython: 3336.21 sec
```

I have a hard time believing Python and Cython (especially Cython) are that slow for the same computation, so I think I must have made an error in my Python/Cython loops, but I can't see where.

Comment: I assume using `np.power` won't speed up things. Also use cython with  annotations (-a option) to see the python interaction, which slows things down.

Comment: This smells of a dupe of [Why is MATLAB so fast in matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6058139/5211833), but given this is about loops, I'll refrain from dupe-hammering for the time being. Anyhow, MATLAB is not Python, so any implementation will inherently be different, both in execution time as well as numerical result. MATLAB is rather expensive, precisely because a lot of work goes into optimisation over naive, unoptimised code in other languages.

Comment: The Python computation is brutally different from that of MATLAB (especially `np.arange()` and `np.power()`)  and the Cython code does not contain any useful speed-up trick. Anyway, I would suggest having a look at Numba.
Also, you should also provide some code to test your code otherwise this is just a lot of guesswork...

Comment: @DavidW It is the same given `i` is an index into an array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes but the Python version assumed that `nech` is an iterable which the MATLAB version assumed that `nech` is a number. However, the code in the question has been edited now though so I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: as @norok2 pointed out in a comment, my approach allocates at least `N*(N-1)/2` doubles due to the use of `pdist`. For your `N = 70299` this means about 18.5 GB of doubles in an array. Other index arrays will have similar size. So unless some of your use cases have smaller `N`, the vectorised approach in this answer is only feasible if you have a lot of memory.

---

As others have noted, just translating code from one language to another will not lead to optimal code in both languages. And using Cython alone is no guarantee for speed-up, in the same way that using NumPy alone is no guarantee for speed-up.

[norok2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704834/5067311) nicely shows you how you can use `numba` or something similar to compile your numerical code. This can give you something quite similar to what you have in MATLAB in terms of performance, since MATLAB has a just-in-time (JIT) compiler of its own. There's also wiggle room to optimize your code for compilation, because multiple implementations can end up with wildly different performance.

Anyway, I want to make the point that you can also speed up your code by using advanced features in NumPy and SciPy. In particular, what you want is to compute pairwise squared distances among a set of 1d points. This is what [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) can do for you (with the `'sqeuclidean'` squared Euclidean norm). The upside is that it only compute each pairwise distance once (which is great for CPU and memory performance), but the downside is that picking out the contributions that you want to sum up a bit more cumbersome.

Anyway, here is the code corresponding to your Python implementation (with the fix that the inner loop uses `np.arange(1, N-i)` rather than `np.arange(1, N-i-1)`):

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def pdisty(f, nech):
    offset = f.size - nech
    res = np.zeros_like(f, shape=nech)
    dists = pdist(f[:, None], metric='sqeuclidean')
    counts = np.arange(offset, f.size)[::-1]
    inds = np.repeat(np.arange(res.size), counts)
    np.add.at(res, inds, dists[:inds.size])
    res /= counts
    return res
```

What happens here is that

1. we compute the pairwise distance of each unique pair of array values and store it to `dists`
2. we compute the number of pairs each point is involved in (this is what we'll have to normalise at the end), store it to `counts`
3. figure out the 1d index of each value in `dists` that it corresponds to (this is the hard part), store it in `inds`
4. use [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to accumulate each contribution to the appropriate output index
5. normalise with the counts.

Here are some timings for `N = 1000`, where `func2()` is the corresponding function from [norok2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704834/5067311):

```
>>> %timeit structFunPython(f, f.size - 1)
... %timeit func2(f, f.size - 1)
... %timeit pdisty(f, f.size - 1)
1.48 s ± 89.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
274 ms ± 2.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
36.7 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The above solution is considerably faster, but of course it's still slower than a fully compiled solution. If you have an issue with additional dependencies or getting llvm installed on your system, this might be a reasonable compromise. The bottom line is that code should be adapted to the language you're trying to optimise it in.

---

For completeness' sake here are the implementations I used for the comparison (I slightly changed the signatures because `N` can be computed from the input array, and I fixed some fencepost errors):

```py
def structFunPython(f, nech):
    """Very slightly modified from the question"""
    N = f.size
    sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    count = np.zeros(nech)
    for i in range(nech):
        indN = np.arange(1,N-i)
        for j in indN:
            sf2[i] += np.power((f[i+j]-f[i]),2)
            count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] = sf2[i]/count[i]
    return sf2


def func2(f_arr, nech):
    """Very slightly modified from norok2's answer

    See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704834/5067311

    """
    n = f_arr.size
    sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    for i in range(nech):
        for j in range(1, n - i):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i + j] - f_arr[i]) ** 2
        sf2[i] /= (n - i - 1)
    return sf2
```

With these definitions all three functions give the same result within machine precision:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
N = 1000
nech = N - 2
f = rng.random(1000)
assert np.allclose(structFunPython(f, nech), func2(f, nech))
assert np.allclose(structFunPython(f, nech), pdisty(f, nech))
```

Answer (score 6):

The way I would rewrite the MATLAB code as equivalent Python code could be (beware of indices starting at 1 in MATLAB and at 0 in Python... since I cannot know how this should be adapted without context I went with the simplest approach):

```py
import numpy as np


def func(f_arr, nech, n):
    sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    count = np.zeros(nech)
    for i in range(nech):
        for j in range(n - i):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i + j] - f_arr[i]) ** 2
            count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] /= count[i]
    return sf2
```

Note that `count[i] += 1` is useless as the final value of `count[i]` is known in advance, and actually the whole `count` is useless, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np


def func2(f_arr, nech, n):
    sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    for i in range(nech):
        for j in range(n - i):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i + j] - f_arr[i]) ** 2
        sf2[i] /= (n - i)
    return sf2
```

---

## Speed-up

This a manual case of Numba speed up. This is just as easy as adding/using a Numba `@njit` decorator:

```py
import numba as nb


func_nb = nb.njit(func)
func2_nb = nb.njit(func2)
```

Now, `func`, `func_nb`, `func2` and `func2_nb` all perform the same computation:

```py
nech = n = 6
f_arr = np.arange(n)
print(func(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
print(func_nb(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
print(func2(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
print(func2_nb(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
```

If you really need to stick to Cython, here is an implementation based on `func2`:

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True


import numpy as np
import cython as cy


cpdef func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n):
    sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    _func2_cy(f_arr.astype(np.float_), sf2, nech, n)
    return sf2


cdef _func2_cy(double[:] f_arr, double[:] sf2, cy.int nech, cy.int n):
    for i in range(nech):
        for j in range(1, n - i):
            sf2[i] = sf2[i] + (f_arr[i + j] - f_arr[i]) ** 2
        sf2[i] = sf2[i] / (n - i)
```

This is significantly more complicated to write compared to Numba, but achieves similar performances.
The trick is to have a function `_func2_cy` which operates with little to no interaction with Python (read: it goes at C speed).

Again the result is the same as `func2`:

```py
nech = n = 6
f_arr = np.arange(n)
print(func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
```

## Timings

With some little toy benchmarking we get a feeling of the speed-ups, including a comparable function written as you did, and the vectorized solution proposed in [Andras Deak's very fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706821/5218354) (but fixing the indices to match the above):

```py
def func_OP(f, nech, n):
    sf2 = np.zeros(n)
    count = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(nech):
        indN = np.arange(n - i)  # <-- indexing fixed
        for j in indN:
            sf2[i] += np.power((f[i+j]-f[i]),2)
            count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] = sf2[i] / count[i]
    return sf2


func_OP_nb = nb.njit(func_OP)
```

```py
def func_pdisty(f, nech, n):
    res = np.zeros(nech)
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(f[:, None], metric='sqeuclidean')
    counts = np.arange(n - 1, n - nech - 1, -1)
    inds = np.repeat(np.arange(res.size), counts)
    np.add.at(res, inds, dists[:inds.size])
    res /= (counts + 1)
    return res
```

```py
nech = n = 6
f_arr = np.arange(n)
print(func_OP(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
print(func_pdisty(f_arr, nech, n))
# [9.16666667 6.         3.5        1.66666667 0.5        0.        ]
```

```py
nech = n = 1000
f_arr = np.arange(n)
%timeit func_OP(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 1.5 s per loop
%timeit func(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 567 ms per loop
%timeit func2(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 352 ms per loop
%timeit func_OP_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.87 ms per loop
%timeit func_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.7 ms per loop
%timeit func2_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 768 µs per loop
%timeit func_pdisty(f_arr, nech, n)
# 10 loops, best of 5: 44.5 ms per loop
%timeit func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1 ms per loop
```

```py
nech = n = 2000
f_arr = np.arange(n)
%timeit func_OP(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 6.01 s per loop
%timeit func(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 2.3 s per loop
%timeit func2(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 1.42 s per loop
%timeit func_OP_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 7.31 ms per loop
%timeit func_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 6.82 ms per loop
%timeit func2_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 3.05 ms per loop
%timeit func_pdisty(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 344 ms per loop
%timeit func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 3.95 ms per loop
```

```py
nech = n = 4000
f_arr = np.arange(n)
%timeit func_OP(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 24.3 s per loop
%timeit func(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 9.27 s per loop
%timeit func2(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 5.71 s per loop
%timeit func_OP_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 10 loops, best of 5: 29 ms per loop
%timeit func_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 10 loops, best of 5: 27.3 ms per loop
%timeit func2_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 12.2 ms per loop
%timeit func_pdisty(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 706 ms per loop
%timeit func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 15.9 ms per loop
```

...and with the input sizes you provided:

```py
nech = 24 * 30 * 24
n = 70299
f_arr = np.random.random(n)
%timeit -n1 -r1 func_OP(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 1: 1h 4min 50s per loop
%timeit -n1 -r1 func(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 1: 21min 14s per loop
%timeit -n1 -r1 func2(f_arr, nech, n)  # only one run / loop
# 1 loop, best of 1: 13min 9s per loop
%timeit func_OP_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 4.74 s per loop
%timeit func_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 4 s per loop
%timeit func2_nb(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 1.62 s per loop
# %timeit func_pdisty(f_arr, nech, n)
# -- MEMORY ERROR --
%timeit func2_cy(f_arr, nech, n)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 2.2 s per loop
```

Comment: If your "loop" is meant as the outer loop, OP's code has `24*30*24 = 17000` of those, resulting in `7.8/17000 = 5e-4`, or about 0.5ms per outer loop calculation (on their system of course).

Comment: I am waiting for the timings with the given input sizes... zzz :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your inner loop has an off-by-one error in the `j` index. OP's code starts from 1, which makes sense because there's no point in computing `f[i] - f[i]`. Then again OP's code probably has an off-by-one error at the end of the `range`, missing the last value.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Possibly, I do not have MATLAB available, so I did not bother fixing this. It is probably something the OP can/should figure out on its own. It will not be relevant for acceleration strategies or timing comparisons.

Comment: Compare to their Python implementation. In general your point about performance is OK, but a faster implementation that gives the wrong result is not very useful :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I am pretty sure those numbers will hold up even with the fixed indices. As you pointed out, the Python implementation is probably bugged, and I provide a OP-like implementation with the same indexing as the others. So what's the point of spending a lot of time for guessing that when this can be easily fixed by OP?

Comment: Nice answer. Just two suggestions regarding your Cython implementation: I think for a fair comparison you should use C-contiguous memoryviews, i.e. `double[::1] f_arr` and `double[::1] sf2`. It's also worth mentioning the used Compiler. On my machine (macOS & gcc), Cython beats the numba implementation whereas numba is often faster on Windows & MSVC. In my experience, this is due to MSVC's bad SIMD-auto-vectorization.

Comment: @joni I am using Google Colab and unsure what version of LLVM / GCC they are using. Specifying C-contiguous memory views `dtype[::1]` (as opposed to `dtype[:]`) translates into identical C code. I think that `dtype[:]` vs `dtype[::1]` is when you are explicitly writing code that requires contiguity, but I do not think Cython provides any further optimization automagically.

Answer (score 5):

You already got some nice answers that presented fast numpy and numba implementations. I'd like to present a decent Cython implementation for a fair comparison.

First of all, let's time norok2's fastest numba implementation on my machine:

```py
In [3]: %timeit func2_nb(f_arr, n)
3.4 s ± 129 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- In order to obtain fast memory access in Cython, it's crucial to give it all the necessary information about the input arrays. In your case, `f_arr` is a C-contiguous np.ndarray, so we use a C-contiguous memoryviews `double[::1]` instead of normal memoryviews `double[:]`. The difference is that indexing a C-contiguous memoryview reduces to plain C code `f_arr[i]` while the latter reduces to `f_arr[i + f_arr.strides[0]]`.
- Next, it's worth mentioning that the Python power operator `a**2` is gonna be substituted by the C code `pow(a,2)`, i.e. we call the `pow`-function. Calling a function in tight loops has unnecessary overhead, even in C. In C, we would just write `a*a`. So let's do the same in Cython.

In Code:

```py
%%cython -c=-O3 -c=-march=native
# for MSVC use: -c=/Ox -c=/arch:AVX2
#           or: -c=/Ox -c=/arch:AVX512 if your CPU supports AVX512 

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def func2_cy(double[::1] f_arr, int nech):
    cdef int n = f_arr.size
    cdef double[::1] sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    cdef int i, j
    for i in range(nech):
        for j in range(n-i-2):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i+j+1]-f_arr[i])*(f_arr[i+j+1]-f_arr[i])
        sf2[i] /= (n - i - 2)
    return np.asarray(sf2)
```

Compiled on my machine with Apple Clang 13.1.6 on macOS, this is slower than the aforementioned numba implementation:

```py
In [5]: %timeit func2_cy(f_arr, n)
4.2 s ± 32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However, one should be aware that Cython is basically just a *Python to C* compiler. This means that after we removed all the python interactions, we can try the same performance tricks we'd apply when using C code: passing the optimization flag `-O3` and enabling all CPU instructions available on the current platform `-march=native`. Note that this also implies that the performance of good Cython code (i.e. code with no python interactions in tight loops) heavily depends on your C Compiler. In my experience, numba is often faster than Cython on Windows due to MSVC's bad auto-vectorization. On macOS/Linux and gcc or clang, it's often the other way around.

One of these well-known performance tricks is loop-unrolling in order to give the compiler hints to SIMD-vectorize the specific loop. Unrolling the innermost loop, the function looks like this:

```py
%%cython -c=-O3 -c=-march=native
# for MSVC use: -c=/Ox -c=/arch:AVX2
#           or: -c=/Ox -c=/arch:AVX512 if your CPU supports AVX512 

#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def func3_cy(double[::1] f_arr, int nech):
    cdef int n = f_arr.size
    cdef double[::1] sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    cdef double fi, fij, fij1, fij2, fij3
    cdef int i, j, ntmp
    for i in range(nech):
        # unroll the inner loop for better SIMD vectorization
        j = 1
        ntmp = (n-i-2) - ((n-i-2) % 4)
        # we use a while-loop since Cython doesn't support range(j, ntmp, 4)
        while j < ntmp:
            # unpack the values and hope the CPU keeps them in its register
            fi   = f_arr[i]
            fij  = f_arr[i+j+1]
            fij1 = f_arr[i+j+2]
            fij2 = f_arr[i+j+3]
            fij3 = f_arr[i+j+4]
            sf2[i] += ((fij-fi)*(fij-fi) + (fij1-fi)*(fij1-fi) + (fij2-fi)*(fij2-fi) + (fij3-fi)*(fij3-fi))
            j += 4
        for j in range(ntmp, n - i - 2):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i+j+1] - f_arr[i]) * (f_arr[i+j+1] - f_arr[i])
        sf2[i] /= (n-i-2)
    return np.asarray(sf2)
```

On my machine, this is nearly two times faster than numba:

```py
In [7]: %timeit func3_cy(f_arr, n)
1.7 s ± 54.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

To take it one step further, we can parallelize the outer loop with the help of [`prange`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html) which is just a thin wrapper around [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP):

```py
%%cython -c=-O3 -c=-march=native -c=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
# for MSVC use: -c=/Ox -c=/openmp -c=/arch:AVX2
#           or: -c=/Ox -c=/openmp -c=/arch:AVX512 if your CPU supports AVX512 

#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def func4_cy(double[::1] f_arr, int nech):
    cdef int n = f_arr.size
    cdef double[::1] sf2 = np.zeros(nech)
    cdef double fi, fij, fij1, fij2, fij3
    cdef int i, j, ntmp
    for i in prange(nech, nogil=True, schedule="static", chunksize=1):
        # unroll the inner loop for better SIMD vectorization
        j = 1
        ntmp = (n-i-2) - ((n-i-2) % 4)
        # we use a while-loop since Cython doesn't support range(j, ntmp, 4)
        while j < ntmp:
            # unpack the values and hope the CPU keeps them in its register
            fi   = f_arr[i]
            fij  = f_arr[i+j+1]
            fij1 = f_arr[i+j+2]
            fij2 = f_arr[i+j+3]
            fij3 = f_arr[i+j+4]
            sf2[i] += ((fij-fi)*(fij-fi) + (fij1-fi)*(fij1-fi) + (fij2-fi)*(fij2-fi) + (fij3-fi)*(fij3-fi))
            j += 4
        for j in range(ntmp, n - i - 2):
            sf2[i] += (f_arr[i+j+1] - f_arr[i]) * (f_arr[i+j+1] - f_arr[i])
        sf2[i] /= (n-i-2)
    return np.asarray(sf2)
```

On my machine with 8 CPU Cores, this is by far the fastest implementation:

```py
In [9]: %timeit func4_cy(f_arr, n)
329 ms ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However, it's worth mentioning that Numba also supports thread parallelism, so I'd expect a similar performance with Numba.

Comment: I generally agree about `pow(a, 2)` -> `a*a` although generally I've found that most C compilers should optimize them to the same thing (so it probably isn't worth worry too much about them). `@cython.boundscheck(False)` is potentially dodgy given that `nech` comes from the caller - it might be worth a little validation at the start of the function.

Comment: And I think `np.array(sf2)` make a copy while `np.asarray(sf2)` probably won't.

Comment: @DavidW I agree that decent C compilers like gcc and clang will optimize it anyway. However, MSVC does not. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/s8hEMG3Eo)'s a simple example that demonstrates that the call to `pow` is still there with the highest optimization flag while gcc and clang will optimize it away. Good hint regarding np.asarray, I must have overlooked that.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm sure I'd tried it on MSVC before and found that it did the optimization, but your test looks fairly conclusive. At very least it isn't reliable

Comment: Good job posting the most on-topic answer :D Fastest too, apparently. Did you check that it gives the same result as OP's one? Just to be on the safe side, in case they copy your answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні At least now it should give the same results as OP's python version. However, I just noticed that OP's Matlab version calculates `(f(i+j)-f(j))**2` while his Python implementation calculates `(f[i+j]-f[i])**2`.. Note that it's `f[i]` and not `f[j]`.

Comment: @joni good catch, I didn't notice that. I think that amount of extra-sensory perception is beyond our responsibility and it's enough if we match their Python code.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the python code. @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні

Answer (score 2):

With some basic python/numpy rewrites I can speed up your code quite a bit

```
def structFunPython4(f,N,nech):
    sf2 = np.zeros(N)
    #count = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(nech):
        # indN = np.arange(1,N-i-1)
        sf2[i] = np.sum(np.power(f[i+1:N-1]-f[i],2))
        #for j in range(1,N-i-1):
        #    sf2[i] += np.power((f[i+j]-f[i]),2)
        #    #count[i] += 1
        sf2[i] = sf2[i]/(N-i-2)
    return sf2
```

For a modest sample size:

```
In [53]: f = np.arange(100); N=f.shape[0]; nech=98
```

they match:

```
In [54]: np.allclose(structFunPython(f,N,nech),structFunPython4(f,N,nech))
Out[54]: True
```

and timings:

```
In [55]: timeit structFunPython(f,N,nech)
34.4 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [56]: timeit structFunPython4(f,N,nech)
2.22 ms ± 35.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I first replaced `for i in indN:` with `for i in range(1,N-1-i):`.  Iteration on an array is slower than iteration on a list or `range`.

As others noted we don't need to iterate the `count`.

But the big change is to replace the `j` iteration with an array slice, power on the whole slice and array sum.

I haven't looked at the `i` iteration enough to eliminate that.  `f[i+1:N-1]` slice varies in length, from `nech` down to 0.

MATLAB does a lot of jit compilation, so you can get by with iterations.  Back in the 1990s when I worked MATLAB that would have been bad form - those versions required whole-matrix calculations to get any reasonable speed. Python level iteration is slow (interpreted), and slower on arrays than on lists.  Try to use whole-array methods where possible.  Or use `numba` to compile the calculations.

====