# Why is my code so slow using Numpy compared to Matlab

Tags: python, performance, matlab, coding-efficiency

I'm sorry for my ignorance in using NumPy and python. I'm much more comfortable in Matlab however I've been required to convert my code from Matlab to Python. To run my script in Python takes 113 seconds meanwhile it takes 7 seconds in MATLAB. Both produce correct results albeit different due to stochasticity. The big culprit I believe is my derivative function. I profiled my python code and it says that this function accounts for 76% of the run time (It doesn't take up nearly as much percent-wise in MATLAB). I understand there is a lot of code so if anyone could help me with making my python derivative code perform more similarly to MATLAB that would be greatly appreciated! If you have any questions feel free to ask. Thank you!

**Derivative6DOF.py**

```
## Derivative6DOF Variables
# Input Variables
# x                   - vehicle state = [x, y, z, u, v, w, phi, theta, psi, p, q, r, omega1, omega2, omega3, omega4]'
# dt                  - time step
# bigOmegasTarget     - commanded rotor speeds = [omega1, omega2, omega3, omega4]'
# batterySOC          - percent battery charge remaining
# m                   - mass of vehicle
# g                   - gravitational acceleration constant
# I                   - moment of inertia = eye([I11, I22, I33]')
# Cd0                 - Profile drag coefficient of each rotor
# pitch               - pitch of blade
# rho                 - density of air
# a                   - lift curve slope of the airfoil
# b                   - number of blades
# c                   - chord length of blade
# R                   - total length of the rotor blade
# viGuessInitial      - guess induced velocity
# posProps            - position of propellers from center of gravity = [x, y, z]'
# A                   - area of propeller
# maxCapacity         - max battery capacity
# powerDrawComponents - power drawn by components from battery
# Kv                  - voltage coefficient of motor [rad/sec/V]
# Kt                  - motor torque coefficent [N*m/A]
# voltMax             - max voltage supplied
# resistanceMotor     - resistance of motor
# PeMax               - max power possible
# Jp                  - inertia about each motor (includes propellor and motor) [kg*m^2]

# Output Variables
# xdot    - vehicle state derivative = [u, v, w, udot, vdot, zdot, p, q, r, pdot, qdot, rdot, omegadot1 omegadot2 omegadot3 omegadot4]'
# battery - battery state = [percentRemaining, dischargeRate]'
# k       - thrust-to-omega coefficient (https://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/physics/quadcopter-dynamics/#:~:text=Each#20rotor#20contributes#20some#20torque,CDAv2.)
# b_coeff - yaw-to-omega coefficient (https://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/physics/quadcopter-dynamics/#:~:text=Each#20rotor#20contributes#20some#20torque,CDAv2.)

# Intermediate Variables
# DCM - rotation matrix from body frame to inertial frame
# UVWp - translational velocity at each propeller = [u, v, w]'
# theta0 - root blade angle
# theta1 - linear twist of blade
# T - thrust
# vi - induced velocity iterated guess
# vPrime - effective speed of flow at the rotor
# viCalc - induced velocity calculated
# Pinduced - induced power
# Pprofile - profile power
# Qp - rotor aerodynamic torque (current motor torque)
# totalThrust - sum of each rotor thrust
# QeMax - max electric motor torque possible
# PeMax - max electric power available
# Qe - electric motor torque (desired motor torque)
# ind - index
# Maero - aerodynamic pitching, rolling and yawing moments = [x, y, z]'
# H - hub forces = [x, y, z]'
# Mgyro - gyroscopic moments = [x, y, z]'
# Cl - coefficient of lift
# AR - aspect ratio
# Cd - coefficient of drag
# lx - distance of props in x-direction
# ly - distance of props in y-direction
# LScale - pitch scalar coefficient
# MScale - roll scalar coefficient
# NScale - yaw scalar coefficient
# MThrust - differential thrust = [x, y, z]'
# F - sum of all forces acting on vehicle
# M - sum of all moments acting on vehicle
# powerDrawMotors - sum of all power draw from all 4 motors
# totalPowerDraw - total power load on battery from all components (motors, camera, electronics, etc.)
# maxBatteryPower = maxCapacity*voltMax/1000; # (Whr) Max possible power from battery at start

# State Element Vector
# x                - x-position
# y                - y-position
# z                - z-position
# u                - x-velocity
# v                - y-velocity
# w                - z-velocity
# udot             - x-acceleration
# vdot             - y-acceleration
# wdot             - z-acceleration
# phi              - angle about y-axis
# theta            - angle about x-axis
# psi              - angle about z-axis
# p                - angular velocity about y-axis
# q                - angular velocity about x-axis
# r                - angular velocity about z-axis
# pdot             - angular acceleration about y-axis
# qdot             - angular acceleration about x-axis
# rdot             - angular acceleration about z-axis
# omega1           - angular speed of front left rotor
# omega2           - angular speed of back right rotor
# omega3           - angular speed of front right rotor
# omega4           - angular speed of back left rotor
# omegadot1        - angular acceleration of front left rotor
# omegadot2        - angular acceleration of back right rotor
# omegadot3        - angular acceleration of front right rotor
# omegadot4        - angular acceleration of back left rotor
# percentRemaining - percent battery charge remaining
# dischargeRate    - discharge rate of battery

# Additional Notes
# Mgyro Derivation Code (Page 639)
# syms p q r Omega Jp
# omega = [0; 0; Jp*Omega]; rotation about positive z-axis
# skewMatrix = [0 -r q; r 0 -p; -q p 0];
# Mgyro = -skewMatrix*omega

import numpy as np

def Derivative6DOF(x,dt,bigOmegasTarget,batterySOC,m,g,I,Cd0,pitch,rho,a,b,c,R,viGuessInitial,posProps,A,maxCapacity,powerDrawComponents,Kv,Kt,voltMax,resistanceMotor,PeMax,Jp,processNoise,theta0,theta1): 
    
    # direction cosine matrix (from bodyframe to NED)
    DCM = np.array([[np.cos(x[8]) * np.cos(x[7]),- np.sin(x[8]) * np.cos(x[6]) + np.cos(x[8]) * np.sin(x[7]) * np.sin(x[6]),np.sin(x[8]) * np.sin(x[6]) + np.cos(x[8]) * np.cos(x[6]) * np.sin(x[7])],[np.cos(x[7]) * np.sin(x[8]),np.cos(x[8]) * np.cos(x[6]) + np.sin(x[8]) * np.sin(x[7]) * np.sin(x[6]),- np.cos(x[8]) * np.sin(x[6]) + np.sin(x[8]) * np.cos(x[6]) * np.sin(x[7])],[- np.sin(x[7]),np.sin(x[6]) * np.cos(x[7]),np.cos(x[7]) * np.cos(x[6])]])
    
    # propeller velocity
    UVWp = np.zeros((4,3))
    for i in range(0,4):
        UVWp[i,:] = x[3:6] + np.cross(x[9:12],posProps[i,:])
    
    T = np.zeros((4,))
    vi = np.ones((4,)) * viGuessInitial
    
    # induced velocity for each rotor
    for i in range(0,4):
        # induced velocity
        vPrime = np.sqrt(UVWp[i,0] ** 2 + UVWp[i,1] ** 2 + (UVWp[i,2] - vi[i]) ** 2)
        T[i] = rho * a * b * c * R / 4 * ((UVWp[i,2] - vi[i]) * x[12 + i] * R + 2 / 3 * (x[12 + i] * R) ** 2 * (theta0 + 0.75 * theta1) + (UVWp[i,0] ** 2 + (UVWp[i,1] ** 2)) * (theta0 + 0.5 * theta1))
        viCalc = T[i] / (2 * rho * A * vPrime)
        
        # converge iterated induced velocity and calculated induced velocity
        while np.abs(vi[i] - viCalc) > 1e-05:

            # induced velocity
            vPrime = np.sqrt(UVWp[i,0] ** 2 + UVWp[i,1] ** 2 + (UVWp[i,2] - vi[i]) ** 2)
            T[i] = rho * a * b * c * R / 4 * ((UVWp[i,2] - vi[i]) * x[12 + i] * R + 2 / 3 * (x[12 + i] * R) ** 2 * (theta0 + 0.75 * theta1) + (UVWp[i,0] ** 2 + (UVWp[i,1] ** 2)) * (theta0 + 0.5 * theta1))
            viCalc = T[i] / (2 * rho * A * vPrime)
            
            # increment the induced velocity guess
            vi[i] = vi[i] + 0.1 * (viCalc - vi[i])

    
    # calculate induced power, profile power, and rotor aerodynamic torque for each rotor
    Pinduced = T*(vi-UVWp[:,2])
    Pprofile = (rho*Cd0*b*c*x[12:16]*R**2/8 * ((x[12:16]*R)**2 + UVWp[:,0]**2 + UVWp[:,1]**2))
    Qp = 1/x[12:16]*(Pinduced + Pprofile)
    
    # calculate total thrust
    totalThrust = np.array([[0],[0],[-np.sum(T)]]).reshape((3,))
    
    # calculate electric motor torque
    QeMax = PeMax / x[12:16]
    Qe = (Kt / resistanceMotor) * (bigOmegasTarget - x[12:16]) / Kv
    
    # confirm electric motor torque isn't exceeding limit
    np.where(Qe > QeMax, Qe, QeMax)
    
    # calculate aerodynamic pitching, rolling, and yawing moments
    Maero = np.zeros((3,))
    Maero[0] = np.sum(np.array([[- 1],[- 1],[1],[1]]) * rho * a * b * c * R**2 * (x[12:16] * R**2 / 16 * x[9] + ((UVWp[:,2] - vi) / 8 + x[12:16] * R * theta0 / 6 + x[12:16] * R * theta1 / 8) * UVWp[:,0]))
    Maero[1] = np.sum(np.array([[- 1],[- 1],[1],[1]]) * rho * a * b * c * R**2 * (x[12:16] * R**2 / 16 * x[10] + ((UVWp[:,2] - vi) / 8 + x[12:16] * R * theta0 / 6 + x[12:16] * R * theta1 / 8) * UVWp[:,1]))
    Maero[2] = np.sum(np.array([[- 1],[- 1],[1],[1]]) * Qe)
    
    # calculate hub force
    H = -np.sign(x[3:6]) * np.sum(rho * Cd0 * b * c * x[12:16] * R**2 / 4 * np.array([UVWp[:,0],UVWp[:,1],np.array([[0],[0],[0],[0]]).reshape(4,)]))
    
    # calculate gyroscopic moments
    Mgyro = np.sum(x[12:16] * np.array([[-1],[-1],[1],[1]]).reshape(4,)) * Jp * np.array([-x[10], x[9], 0]).reshape((3,))
    
    # calculate thrust-to-omega coefficient
    k = T / x[12:16]**2
    
    # calculate yaw-to-omega coefficient
    Cl = 2 * T / (rho * R**2 * x[12:16]**2)
    AR = R**2 / A
    Cd = Cd0 + Cl**2 / (np.pi * AR * 1)
    b_coeff = 0.5 * R ** 3 * rho * Cd * A
    
    # calculate motor-mixer scalar coefficients
    lx = np.abs(posProps[:,0])
    ly = np.abs(posProps[:,1])
    LScale = k * ly
    MScale = k * lx
    NScale = b_coeff
    
    # calculate differential thrust
    MThrust = np.zeros((3,))
    MThrust[0] =  np.sum(x[12:16]**2 * np.array([1,-1,-1,1]).reshape((4,)) * LScale)
    MThrust[1] =  np.sum(x[12:16]**2 * np.array([1,-1,1,-1]).reshape((4,)) * MScale)
    MThrust[2] =  np.sum(x[12:16]**2 * np.array([-1,-1,1,1]).reshape((4,)) * NScale)
    
    # total force and moment acting on quadcopter in inertial frame
    F = DCM @ (totalThrust + H)
    M = DCM @ (Maero + Mgyro + MThrust)
    
    # calculate state derivative
    xdot = np.zeros((16,))
    xdot[0:3] = np.array([x[3],x[4],x[5]])
    
    xdot[3] = F[0] / m
    xdot[4] = F[1] / m
    xdot[5] = g + F[2] / m
    
    xdot[6] = x[9] + np.tan(x[7]) * np.sin(x[6]) * x[10] + np.tan(x[7]) * np.cos(x[6]) * x[11]
    xdot[7] = np.cos(x[6]) * x[10] - np.sin(x[6]) * x[11]
    xdot[8] = 1/np.cos(x[7]) * np.sin(x[6]) * x[10] + 1/np.cos(x[7]) * np.cos(x[6]) * x[11]
    
    xdot[9] = (M[0] + x[10] * x[11] * (I[1,1] - I[2,2])) / I[0,0]
    xdot[10] = (M[1] + x[9] * x[11] * (I[2,2] - I[0,0])) / I[1,1]
    xdot[11] = (M[2] + x[9] * x[10] * (I[0,0] - I[1,1])) / I[2,2]
    
    xdot[12:16] = 1/Jp * (Qe - Qp)
    
    xdot = xdot + np.random.randn(16,) * processNoise
    
    # calculate battery state
    powerDrawMotors = np.sum(Qp * x[12:16])
    totalPowerDraw = powerDrawMotors + powerDrawComponents
    maxBatteryPower = maxCapacity * voltMax / 1000
    discharge = totalPowerDraw * dt / 3600 / maxBatteryPower * 100
    batterySOC = batterySOC - discharge
    battery = np.array([[batterySOC],[discharge]]).reshape((2,))
    
    return xdot,battery,k,b_coeff,vi
```

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication

Comment: I won't read this whole code but an obvious thing is the use of nested `for` and `while` loops, this is certainly not vectorial (i.e. slow).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The link posted in the comment above about matrix multiplication is a red herring. [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Matlab+python+slow) gives hundreds of questions about why Python is slower than MATLAB. Python is significantly slower in execution than MATLAB. If you limit your script to calling built-in functionality that does the heavy lifting, then there's not much difference, but if you do lots of looping to process individual array elements, then Python is going to be orders of magnitude slower than MATLAB. Look for Numba to speed up your Python functions.