# Eigen3 Matrix-Matrix Multiplication 30 times faster than own openmp parallelized code

Tags: visual-c++, matrix-multiplication, eigen3

I compiled the code below on VS C++ 2017 with /openmp /O2 /arch::AVX. 
When running with 8 threads the output is:

dt_loops = 1562ms
dt_eigen = 26 ms

I expected the A * B to be faster than my own handmade loops but I did not expect such a large difference. Is there anything wrong with my code? And if not how can Eigen3 do it so much faster.

I'm not very experienced in using OpenMP or any other parallelization method. I tried diferent loop orders but the one below is the fastest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start1, end1, start2, end2;

    int n = 1000;
    Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(n, n);
    Eigen::MatrixXd B = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(n, n);
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(n, n);

    start1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int i, j, k;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                C(i, j) += A(i, k) * B(k, j);
            }
        }
    }
    end1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "dt_loops = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end1-start1).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    Eigen::MatrixXd D = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(n, n);

    start2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    D = A * B;
    end2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "dt_eigen = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end2-start2).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to consider things like caching, blocking, and SIMD for optimal performance of matrix products.

Comment: You can get some speed up by reordering your loops: `j, k, i`. This way the compiler will be able to leverage SIMD (at least clang, gcc, and icc), you'll gain on pipelining, and also a bit on cache misses. But of course to reach Eigen's speed much more work are needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does BLAS get such extreme performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303182/how-does-blas-get-such-extreme-performance) -- not exactly a duplicate of course, but generally the same question.