# Speed up N-d array dot

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do some matrix computations as

```
def get_P(X,Z):
    n_sample,n_m,n_t,n_f = X.shape
    res = np.zeros((n_sample,n_m,n_t,n_t))
    for i in range(n_sample):
        res[i,:,:,:] = np.dot(X[i,:,:,:],Z[i,:,:])
    return res
```

Because the size of X and Z is large, it takes more than 600ms to compute one np.dot, and I have 10k rows in X.

Is there anyway we can speed it up?

Comment: I could very easily be misunderstanding it, but from reading the docs, I get the impression that `res = np.dot(X,Z)` gives the same result. I don't know if that's any fast, though.

Comment: There may be some ways, but without knowing the approx. shape of the arrays it is hard to give a general answer. Always provide a full working example including realistic shape and size of input arrays. This is an example on quite small (2x2) matrices https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774

Comment: res = np.dot(X,Z) won't give the same results and will give errors. However np.matmul(Xtmp,Z[:,None,:,:]) will give the same results and three times faster but not that faster enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there might be some avoidable overhead posed by your zero initialization (which gets overwritten right away): Just use `np.ndarray` instead.

Other than that: numpy is fairly well-optimized. Probably you can speed things up if you used `dtype=numpy.float32` instead of the default 64-bit floating point numbers for your `X`, `Z` and `res` – but that's about it. Dot products are mostly spending time going linear through RAM and multiplying and summing numbers – things that numpy, compilers and CPUs are radically good at these days.

Note that numpy will only use one CPU core at a time in its default configuration - it might make sense to parallelize; for example, if you've got 16 CPU cores, you'd make 16 separate `res` partitions and calculate subsets of your `range(n_sample)` dot products on each core; python does bring the multithreading / `async` facilities to do so – you'll find plenty of examples, and explaining how would lead too far.

If you can spend the development time, and need massive amounts of data, so that this pays: you can use e.g. GPUs to multiply matrices; these are [really good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404232/why-is-numpy-dot-as-fast-as-these-gpu-implementations-of-matrix-multiplication) at that, and cuBLASlt (GEMM) is an excellent implementation, but honestly, you'd mostly be abandoning Numpy and would need to work things out yourself – in C/C++.

Comment: `np.ndarray` is considered a low-level constructor, and `np.zeros` or `np.empty` is preferred.  See its docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy `einsum` to do this multiplication in one vectorized step.
It will be much faster than this `loop` based dot product. For examples, check this link https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum