# Speed Up a for Loop - Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have a code that works perfectly well but I wish to speed up the time it takes to converge. A snippet of the code is shown below:

```
def myfunction(x, i):
    y = x + (min(0, target[i] - data[i, :]x))*data[i]/(norm(data[i])**2))
    return y
rows, columns = data.shape

start = time.time()
iterate = 0
iterate_count = []
norm_count = []
res = 5

x_not = np.ones(columns)
norm_count.append(norm(x_not))
iterate_count.append(0)

while res > 1e-8:
    for row in range(rows):
        y = myfunction(x_not, row)
        x_not = y
    iterate += 1
    iterate_count.append(iterate)
    norm_count.append(norm(x_not))
    res = abs(norm_count[-1] - norm_count[-2])

print('Converge at {} iterations'.format(iterate))
print('Duration: {:.4f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

I am relatively new in Python. I will appreciate any hint/assistance.

Ax=b is the problem we wish to solve. Here, 'A' is the 'data' and 'b' is the 'target'

Comment: What's in `myfunction`? _That's_ what you need to optimize. The rest of the code just does simple arithmetic and appending to lists

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi 'myfunction' is just a one line formular as well. I had thought there would be a better way to handle the for and while loops

Comment: There is, depending on what's in `myfunction`. Look up vectorization. If you can express your problem as a vector/matrix calculation, you can use numpy's functions that implement SIMD operations to get a significant speedup.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi do you think this is feasible in a function of this type:

'def myfunction(x, i):
    y = x + (min(0, target[i] - data[i, :] @ x))*(data[i] / (norm(data[i])**2))
    return y'

Comment: Please [edit] that info into your question.

Comment: Also, please explain what that function is supposed to do. What is `data`? What shape does it have? What about `target`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I just did. Thank you

Comment: Is this an exercise or are you looking for the best way to do this? You're solving a linear system of equations, there are preexisting ways to do this if you're looking for the best solution.

Comment: I know there are best ways to get it done but I am just trying something different.

Comment: Okay hold tight. I'm writing an answer.

Comment: FYI: This is going to take a while, it isn't as straightforward as I originally thought

Comment: I do not mind to chill till you can have time. I would be glad to learn from you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh! After spending a while on this I don't think it can be done the way you've set up your problem. In each iteration over the row, you modify `x_not` and then pass the updated result to get the solution for the next row. This kind of setup can't be vectorized easily. You can learn the thought process of vectorization from the failed attempt, so I'm including it in the answer. I'm also including a different iterative method to solve linear systems of equations. I've included a vectorized version -- where the solution is updated using matrix multiplication and vector addition, and a loopy version -- where the solution is updated using a `for` loop to demonstrate what you can expect to gain.

## 1. The failed attempt

Let's take a look at what you're doing here.

```
def myfunction(x, i): 
    y = x + (min(0, target[i] - data[i, :] @ x)) * (data[i] / (norm(data[i])**2)) 
    return y
```

- You subtract

  - the dot product of (the `i`th row of `data` and `x_not`)
  - from the `i`th row of `target`,
  - limited at zero.
- You multiply this result with the `i`th row of `data` divided my the norm of that row squared. Let's call this `part2`
- Then you add this to the `i`th element of `x_not`

Now let's look at the shapes of the matrices.

- `data` is `(M, N)`.
- `target` is `(M, )`.
- `x_not` is `(N, )`

Instead of doing these operations rowwise, you can operate on the *entire matrix!*

### 1.1. Simplifying the dot product.

Instead of doing `data[i, :] @ x`, you can do `data @ x_not` and this gives an array with the `i`th element giving the dot product of the `i`th row with `x_not`. So now we have `data @ x_not` with shape `(M, )`

Then, you can subtract this from the entire `target` array, so `target - (data @ x_not)` has shape `(M, )`.

So far, we have

```
part1 = target - (data @ x_not)
```

Next, if anything is greater than zero, set it to zero.

```
part1[part1 > 0] = 0
```

### 1.2. Finding rowwise norms.

Finally, you want to multiply this by the row of `data`, and divide by the square of the L2-norm of that row. To get the norm of each row of a matrix, you do

```
rownorms = np.linalg.norm(data, axis=1)
```

This is a `(M, )` array, so we need to convert it to a `(M, 1)` array so we can divide each row. `rownorms[:, None]` does this. Then divide `data` by this.

```
part2 = data / (rownorms[:, None]**2)
```

### 1.3. Add to `x_not`

Finally, we're adding *each row of* `part1 * part2` to the original `x_not` and returning the result

```
result = x_not + (part1 * part2).sum(axis=0)
```

**Here's where we get stuck**. In your approach, each call to `myfunction()` gives a value of `part1` that depends on `target[i]`, which was changed in the last call to `myfunction()`.

## 2. Why vectorize?

Using `numpy`'s inbuilt methods instead of looping allows it to offload the calculation to its C backend, so it runs faster. If your numpy is linked to a [BLAS backend](https://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html), [you can extract *even* more speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303182/how-does-blas-get-such-extreme-performance) by using your processor's SIMD registers

The [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) is a simple iterative method to solve certain systems of equations. There are other more complex algorithms that can solve general systems well, but this should do for the purposes of our demo. Again, the purpose is not to have an iterative algorithm that will perfectly solve *any* linear system of equations, but to show what kind of speedup you can expect if you vectorize your code.

Given your system

```
data @ x_not = target
```

Let's define some variables:

```
A = data.T @ data
b = data.T @ target
```

And we'll solve the system `A @ x = b`

```
x = np.zeros((columns,)) # Initial guess. Can be anything
resid = b - A @ x
p = resid

while (np.abs(resid) > tolerance).any():
        Ap = A @ p
        alpha = (resid.T @ resid) / (p.T @ Ap)
        x = x + alpha * p
        resid_new = resid - alpha * Ap
        beta = (resid_new.T @ resid_new) / (resid.T @ resid)
        p = resid_new + beta * p
        resid = resid_new + 0
```

---

To contrast the fully vectorized approach with one that uses iterations to update the rows of `x` and `resid_new`, let's define another implementation of the CG solver that does this.

```
def solve_loopy(data, target, itermax = 100, tolerance = 1e-8):
    A = data.T @ data
    b = data.T @ target
    
    rows, columns = data.shape
        
    x = np.zeros((columns,)) # Initial guess. Can be anything
    resid = b - A @ x
    resid_new = b - A @ x
    p = resid
    
    niter = 0
    while (np.abs(resid) > tolerance).any() and niter < itermax:
        Ap = A @ p
        alpha = (resid.T @ resid) / (p.T @ Ap)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            x[i] = x[i] + alpha * p[i]
            resid_new[i] = resid[i] - alpha * Ap[i] 
        # resid_new = resid - alpha * A @ p
        beta = (resid_new.T @ resid_new) / (resid.T @ resid)
        p = resid_new + beta * p
        resid = resid_new + 0
        niter += 1
    
    return x
```

And our original vector method:

```
def solve_vect(data, target, itermax = 100, tolerance = 1e-8):
    
    A = data.T @ data
    b = data.T @ target
    
    rows, columns = data.shape

    x = np.zeros((columns,)) # Initial guess. Can be anything
    resid = b - A @ x
    resid_new = b - A @ x
    p = resid
    
    niter = 0
    while (np.abs(resid) > tolerance).any() and niter < itermax:
        Ap = A @ p
        alpha = (resid.T @ resid) / (p.T @ Ap)
        x = x + alpha * p
        resid_new = resid - alpha * Ap
        beta = (resid_new.T @ resid_new) / (resid.T @ resid)
        p = resid_new + beta * p
        resid = resid_new + 0
        niter += 1
    
    return x
```

Let's solve a simple system to see if this works first:

```
2x1 +   x2  =   -5
−x1 +   x2  =   -2
```

should give a solution of `[-1, -3]`

```
data = np.array([[ 2,  1],
       [-1,  1]])
target = np.array([-5, -2])
print(solve_loopy(data, target))
print(solve_vect(data, target))
```

Both give the correct solution `[-1, -3]`, yay! Now on to bigger things:

```
data = np.random.random((100, 100))
target = np.random.random((100, ))
```

Let's ensure the solution is still correct:

```
sol1 = solve_loopy(data, target)
np.allclose(data @ sol1, target)
# Output: False

sol2 = solve_vect(data, target)
np.allclose(data @ sol2, target)
# Output: False
```

Hmm, looks like the CG method doesn't work for badly conditioned random matrices we created. Well, at least both give the *same* result.

```
np.allclose(sol1, sol2)
# Output: True
```

But let's not get discouraged! We don't really care if it works perfectly, the point of this is to demonstrate how amazing vectorization is. So let's time this:

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('solve_loopy(data, target)', number=10, setup='from __main__ import solve_loopy, data, target')
# Output: 0.25586539999994784

timeit.timeit('solve_vect(data, target)', number=10, setup='from __main__ import solve_vect, data, target')
# Output: 0.12008900000000722
```

Nice! A ~2x speedup *simply by avoiding a loop while updating our solution!*

For larger systems, this will be even better.

```
for N in [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]:
    data = np.random.random((N, N))
    target = np.random.random((N, ))

    t_loopy = timeit.timeit('solve_loopy(data, target)', number=10, setup='from __main__ import solve_loopy, data, target')
    t_vect = timeit.timeit('solve_vect(data, target)', number=10, setup='from __main__ import solve_vect, data, target')
    print(N, t_loopy, t_vect, t_loopy/t_vect)
```

This gives us:

```
    N     t_loopy      t_vect     speedup
00010    0.002823    0.002099    1.345390
00050    0.051209    0.014486    3.535048
00100    0.260348    0.114601    2.271773
00500    0.980453    0.240151    4.082644
01000    1.769959    0.508197    3.482822
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should try the loop and vectorize approach on GMRES to appreciate this. I appreciate your time.